# Adding a line break in MySQL INSERT INTO text

Tags: mysql, newline, insert-into

Could someone tell me how to add a new line in a text that I enter in a MySql table?

I tried using the `'\n'` in the line I entered with `INSERT INTO` statement but `'\n'` is shown as it is.

Actually I have created a table in MS Access with some data. MS Access adds new line with `'\n'`.  I am converting MS Access table data into MySql . But when I convert, the `'\n'` is ignored and all the text is shown in one single line when I display it from MySql table on a PHP form.

Can anyone tell me how MySQL can add a new line in a text? Awaiting response, thanks!!

Comment: Find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41448185/5466401

Answer (score 90):

If you're OK with a SQL command that spreads across multiple lines, then [oedo's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902888/adding-a-line-break-in-mysql-insert-into-text/2902913#2902913) suggestion is the easiest:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES ('hi this is some text
and this is a linefeed.
and another');
```

I just had a situation where it was preferable to have the SQL statement all on one line, so I found that a combination of [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and [`CHAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char) worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES (CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 using utf8), 'hi this is some text', 'and this is a linefeed.', 'and another'));
```

Comment: Isn't a combination of `CARRIAGE RETURN` and `LINE FEED` by using `CHAR(13)` and `CHAR(10)` usually recommended for compatibility? `CR` is equivalent to `\r` and `LF` is equivalent to `\n`

Comment: What's wrong in CHAR(10 USING ASCII)?

Answer (score 40):

in an actual SQL query, you just add a newline

```
INSERT INTO table (text) VALUES ('hi this is some text
and this is a linefeed.
and another');
```

Answer (score 30):

For the record, I wanted to add some line breaks into existing data and I got `\n` to work ok...

Sample data:

```
Sentence. Sentence. Sentence
```

I did:

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '. ', '.\r\n')
```

However, it also worked with just `\r` and just `\n`.

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work if you have abbreviations in your text, like "Mr. Smith", which will be broken into 2 lines.

Comment: thanks, that was helpful for my situation where I am doing parsing and can't separate onto actual lines in the insert

Comment: Be aware that in general you want to use only \n if in a UNIX server environment, and \r\n if in a Windows-only server environment. Do not use \r on its own. Here's a discussion on what these mean, except be aware that information abuot "Mac" using "\r" is woefully outdated - Macs have been using the standard Unix "LF" (\n) exclusively for about 15 years. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types

Comment: @XP84 Good point! I would go even further and take the stance that the text in the DB should be platform-agnostic and hence use `\n` only. This is the way most such systems are dealing with it. E.g. Git. Optionally you can replace `\n` with `\r\n` upon reading on a Windows system, but mostly you'll find it's not even needed. Most Windows components will just work with only `\n`. Notepad is a notable exception to this.

Comment: Wonderful! I had converted a database, and the '\n' and '\r' characters got inserted by mistake. I took care of it in a mere two statements: `UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '\\r', '\r');` and
`UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '\\n', '\n');`

Comment: @dhc, you could also do that update in a single statement: `UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '\\r', '\r'), '\\n', '\n');`

Answer (score 22):

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES('a line\nanother line');
```

`\n` just works fine here

Comment: @JordanSilva and upvoters of his comment: check out [the answer by David M](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2902909/286685) it probably contains your solution.

Comment: @StijndeWitt It was long ago and I don't remember how I solved the problem. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 17):

MySQL can record linebreaks just fine in most cases, but the problem is, you need `<br />` tags in the actual string for your browser to show the breaks. Since you mentioned PHP, you can use the **`nl2br()`** function to convert a linebreak character ("`\n`") into HTML `<br />` tag.

Just use it like this:

```
<?php
echo nl2br("Hello, World!\n I hate you so much");
?>
```

Output (*in HTML*):

```
Hello, World!<br>I hate you so much
```

Here's a link to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Note: the default `<br>` style is actually `<br />`

Answer (score 12):

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES("First line\r\nSecond line\r\nThird line");
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, if you want it displayed on a PHP form, the medium is HTML and so a new line will be rendered with the `<br />` tag. Check the source HTML of the page - you may possibly have the new line rendered just as a line break, in which case your problem is simply one of translating the text for output to a web browser.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL or MySQL you can use the `char` or `chr` functions to enter in an ASCII 13 for carriage return line feed, the `\n` equivilent. But as @David M has stated, you are most likely looking to have the HTML show this break and a br is what will work.

Comment: ASCII 13 isn't `\r`?  Thought `\n` was ASCII 10.

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to replace `\n` with `<br/>` before inset into database.

   `$data = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $data);`

   In this case in database table you will see `<br/>` instead of new line.

   e.g.

   `First Line`
   `Second Line`

   will look like:

   `First Line<br/>Second Line`
2. Another way to view data with new line. First read data from database. And then replace `\n` with `<br/>` e.g. :

   `echo $data;`
   `$data = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $data);`
   `echo "<br/><br/>" . $data;`

   output:

   `First Line Second Line`
   `First Line`
   `Second Line`

   You will find details about function str_replace() here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: You should use PHP native function [nl2br()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) instead of str_replace to do this.

Comment: Agreed - you should always avoid putting HTML into your database. That should be done in your code - keep raw data in the tables.

Comment: Indeed. Please never include raw HTML in the text in the DB... It will become a maintenance nightmare. What are you going to do when someone uses the normal characters `<`, `>` and `&` in their text... escape it? If so, how are you going to avoid escaping the `<br/>` you inserted? You will create a problem that cannot be solved.

Comment: @Scott :: As far i know most of the rich text editor put HTML code in database. So it depends how you handle code.

Comment: @StijndeWitt :: Depending on situation you can easily use regular expression to detect HTML tags to avoid during escaping special characters.

Comment: @Airful Don't. Because you'll always leave a security breach somewhere.

Comment: @Xenos you have to perform XSS on output to overcome this isseu.

Answer (score 0):

use `<pre>` tag instead of `<p>` in html to show your `\n` in database

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer given @DonKirby

```
INSERT INTO mytable (myfield) VALUES (CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10 using utf8), 'hi this is some text', 'and this is a linefeed.', 'and another'));
```

is unnecessary

The `CHAR()` function doesn't accept the full set of `utf8` values. It accepts only `ASCII` values.

See - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char

Thus more appropriate would be to use `CHAR(10 USING ASCII)` in place of `CHAR(10 USING utf8)`

Comment: If that's the case, then why not just use `CHAR(10)`?

Answer (score -3):

You can simply replace all `\n` with `<br/>` tag so that when page is displayed then it breaks line.

```
UPDATE table SET field = REPLACE(field, '\n', '<br/>')
```