# new line in SQL insert query

Tags: sql

I want to use the following statement to add a row in a table named people with one column which is varchar(100)

insert into people values ('a b')

I want to have a new line between a and b.

How to do this?

I tried something like 'a CHAR(13) b' but did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a line break in MySQL INSERT INTO text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902888/adding-a-line-break-in-mysql-insert-into-text)

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
'a ' + CHAR(13) + ' b'
```

Comment: I normally do Cr and Ln: `'a ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + ' b'`

Answer (score 1):

This works as well:

```
'a' +  CRLF + 'b'
```

Check this link as well

[How to insert a line break in a SQL Server VARCHAR/NVARCHAR string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31057/how-to-insert-a-line-break-in-a-sql-server-varchar-nvarchar-string)