# mySQL Query String in Perl does not seem to handle '\n'

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to replace newline characters in the DB with `<br/>` tags and have the following mySQL query string written in Perl.

```
my $queryString = "Select REPLACE(r.form_text,'\n','<br /> '), ... FROM myTable r;"
```

For some reason, `\n` is treated as a newline from within perl and does not seem to replace it with `<br/>`. Here is what I got when I tried to print `$queryString`

```
REPLACE(r.form_text,'

','< br /> ')
```

I tried to use `\\n` and `\\\n` and it didn't work either. I apologize if this is a repeated question. Please let me know if I'm missing something here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902888/adding-a-line-break-in-mysql-insert-into-text

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get a newline. When you use double quotes to quote a string anything inside it is interpolated, and `\n` becomes a literal newline. If you want a literal `\n`, you need to prevent interpolation. Usually, you would use single quotes, but that is impractical since you have those in the string already. So instead, use the `q()` feature.

```
my $queryString = 
    q|Select REPLACE(r.form_text,'\n','<br /> '), ... FROM myTable r;|;
```

Note that you can use a wide variety of delimiters for `q()`, in this case, I used pipe `|`. If you try and print this string, it should have a literal `\n`. Documentation [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: On the flip side, the query should still have worked as intended even with a literal newline...

Comment: Thanks a lot @TLP. That's something I learnt new today. But it prints as Select REPLACE(r.form_text,'\\n','<br /> ') FROM myTable r; Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Me neither.. when I try it, I get `\n`.