# Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im using MYSQL Workbench in my project,while inserting data into a table I got an error
`Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`. The query I use was the following `insert into user(user_name,password,type,specialize,f_name,address,phone,email,designation,institute,in_email) values('salini','salu','setter','SE','salini','Sreesailam SRPMPO thazhava karunagappally','8000000000','salureju@gmail.com','HOD','SNT','snt@gmail.com')` here the field address has the datatype Multiline String. Is that is the error?? All other fields are int and varchar. How can i solve this?

Comment: plz somebody help me to solve this problem

Comment: can you post the results of `describe table user`?  It appears from the error message you've posted that one or more columns are spatial-enabled.

Comment: @MarkS Yes You are correct. She might enabled the Geometry datatype instead of Multiline or something.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short answer

Addresses in [postal format](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_001.htm#ep526236) should probably use the `varchar` data type, since MySQL’s regular text data types are quite capable of storing strings with line breaks, and addresses have a limited length.

#### Explanation

The `multilinestring` data type is (counter-intuitively) for storing [*geometry* data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-class-multilinestring.html), not text data. To store text data, use one of MySQL’s [string data types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-types.html). While two below are the most common, other types do exist for more specialized use cases.

- `varchar` for strings up to a certain number of characters long. Specify the max length in parentheses, like `varchar(255)`.
- `text` for strings that might take more storage space than MySQL and your database engine would normally allow in a single row.

Storing a string with line breaks in MySQL depends on [how you write your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902888/adding-a-line-break-in-mysql-insert-into-text), and might be as simple as surrounding the string in parentheses and quotes.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50245905/15016042) for pointing me in the right direction!