# Escape sequence \f - form feed - what exactly is it?

Tags: c++, escaping

`\f` is said to be the form feed. `\t` is a tab, `\a` is a beep, `\n` is a newline. What exactly is a form feed - `\f`? The following program

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   std::cout << "hello\fgoodbye" << std::endl;  
}
```

prints `hello` then a ***female sign*** (an upside down [holy hand grenade](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_tEXBaE1b0tA/S-iL1oTVhKI/AAAAAAAABZs/F4nGxS5X3Fc/s1600/grenade.jpeg):) and then `goodbye` all on one line.

Comment: In the GNOME terminal and `xterm`, it gives a newline+space. Does `isspace('\f')` return true for you?

Comment: @larsmans: As a matter of fact, strangely it *does* return true but prints the female sign anyway :)

Comment: Maybe when sent to a very old printer \f forces a form feed?

Comment: what misogynistic platform are you on?

Comment: @larsmans: Windows XP, MSVC9.0 compiler

Comment: interestingly, if you use pdftotext in linux to convert a pdf file into text, you will find that the new pages are demarkated with a \f

Comment: Since it's upside down, does that make it an unholy hand grenade?

Comment: _Upside down holy hand grenade_. Wonderful.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It skips to the start of the next page. (Applies mostly to terminals where the output device is a printer rather than a VDU.)

Comment: It does for me. Perhaps your terminal is broken in some way.

Comment: Check that your acoustic coupler is seated correctly and your daisywheel is aligned.

Comment: @Tim Robinson, my brain is imagining sounds I haven't heard for almost 20 years. Thank you soooo much :-(

Comment: VDU means 'Visual Display Unit', e.g. a monitor.

Answer (score 39):

From [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

> 12 (form feed, \f, ^L), to cause a
>   printer to eject paper to the top of
>   the next page, or a video terminal to
>   clear the screen.

or more details [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break).

It seems that this symbol is rather obsolete now and the way it is processed may be(?) implementation dependent. At least for me your code gives the following output (xcode gcc 4.2, gdb console):

```
hello
    goodbye
```

Comment: It's implementation-dependent in the sense that the way it is processed is up to the application/device receiving it, not the C++ program, which should just write it to the appropriate stream.

Comment: It's not really obsolete, as there are still circumstances where you will write (extended) ASCII directly to a printer, for example when using receipt printers. It's not something you will need to use in a terminal, though.

Answer (score 17):

If you were programming for a 1980s-style printer, it would eject the paper and start a new page. You are virtually certain to never need it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_feed

Comment: ^L formfeed is utilized to this day as a section-separator in plain text files, such as source code for computer-programming languages.  When a text file gets lengthy and the first, say, 568 lines are one kind of thingy and the next 729 lines are a different kind of thingy, then often we put a ^L formfeed character at the beginning of line 569, often giving the ^L formfeed character its own line.  Sometimes ^K vertical-tab and ^L are utilized together in this section-separator scheme with ^K for separating minor sections and ^L for separating major sections.

Answer (score 10):

It comes from the era of [Line Printers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_printer) and green-striped [fan-fold paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan-fold).

Trust me, you ain't gonna need it...

Answer (score 4):

Although recently its use is undefined, a common and useful use for the form feed is to separate sections of code vertically, like so:
[image]
(from http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_form_feed_section_paging.html)

Answer (score -1):

It's go to newline then add spaces to start second line at end of first line

Output

```
Hello
     Goodbye
```

Comment: This is not really the case for `\f`. This describes the vertical tab, e.g. `\v` (not sure if c++ has this). It could be the case that the form feed (next page) is interpreted this way in a terminal or whatever. See also [CB Bailey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4334399/2648551).