# What does "^L" mean in C?

Tags: c

For example, `main` in `src/hello.c` in the GNU Hello package ends like this:

```
   exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
 ^L
```

Comment: It means that the program's done ... to L with it!

Comment: I'm wondering though if that is an actual FF and the editor simply shows it like ^L, or if it's the characters "^L". If I were an editor, I'd show an FF like "♀" or "␌".

Comment: @MrLister: Then you would wonder if it's an actual FF or the characters ♀ or ␌. ;-)

Comment: `^L` is a Control-L or ASCII FORM FEED, to eject the page.  The C compiler normally ignores it, and the editor shows it as shown in your sample.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape sequence \f - form feed - what exactly is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334370/escape-sequence-f-form-feed-what-exactly-is-it)

Comment: @phuclv it is different because the `^L` is not used here as an escape code in a string.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Literally, it's a page break ("form feed") character.  The compiler treats it as ordinary whitespace. But it's very useful for printing source code - it starts a new page (for example, use `^L` between functions to force each call to get its own page).

In [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)/vi based editors, you can insert such a character within edit mode by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>. It will look like `^L` in the editor, but it's actually just one character (ASCII value: 12 or 0x0C).

In other words, `^L` does this:

[image]

Comment: "it starts a new page" elaborate on this? What do you mean by a page exactly?

Comment: If you would print the source code on paper, the printer would… start a new page.

Comment: Literally [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/1ODM8ZlEpcZl6/giphy.gif)

Comment: Some text editors have keystroke commands to jump to the next or previous `^L` character, and some can also hide all of the text between two `^L` characters.

Comment: This is the worst concept i have ever seen during my programming life.

Comment: @Croll Obviously that's been a short life. You've never had to deal with hundreds of pages of listing s from a line printer. You'd use it all right.

Comment: @Croll Well, it's hardly the first time someone's used whitespace to make code format nicely, is it?

Comment: Actually, you can do the same insertion with an ASR33 Teletype.

Comment: @user207421 - I can remember the good ole days, when, if the compiler wasn't smart enough to automatically do it at the start of a procedure you'd insert `@eject` or some such, to get to the top of the next neatly folded page of form-feed paper.  Made reviewing code **much** easier.

Comment: Vertical tabs and form feed are still widely used, but for C we have a lot of pretty print alternatives. Very normal in the mainframe world too.

Comment: Ooh, so you use a device that resembles a 3D printer, but it prints very flat objects very fast... That's a pretty neat concept. I doubt you could find one for a reasonable price though because it looks like it caters to a very small niche market.

Answer (score 1):

it is also called form feed.It is a page-breaking ASCII control character. It forces the printer to eject the current page and to continue printing at the top of another. It will also cause a carriage return. The form feed character code is defined as `12` 
`(0xC in hexadecimal)`