# About escape sequence in c

Tags: c, escaping

Some details about \f (form fill) escape sequence. When I searched it on google it show that it will provide a page break. But when I tried it on Code blocks it show some female sign.

Comment: Probably find some information here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/4334399/14436359

Comment: I remember 35 years ago sending a couple of hundred of these at once to the high-speed line printer in the prn-out room at college. Shot paper all the way to the ceiling. Good times.