# How to print text starting from the top left corner of console on linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I want to print some dynamic status text message starting from the top left corner of console, leaving the left area blank on linux(something like `watch -n 1 pwd`). How can I do it using C or C++?

Comment: Look for something like ncurses maybe.

Comment: Use the termcap database to find the terminal's control sequences for cursor positioning, or use a Curses library (such as ncurses) which can abstract all that behind higher-level concepts such as windows and widgets.

Comment: Did you read how `watch` works?  Since you have an example of what you want to do, it's likely a good idea to read its sources to find how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance that your terminal supports [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). These provide a way of altering terminal output properties, controlling cursors, etc.

In the program below `ESC` is defined to be an escape code prefix, `CLS` is defined to be the control sequence that clears a screen, and `HOME` is defined to be the control sequence that moves the cursor to its home position at the top left of the console window. Printing these codes to a terminal window should have the desired effect in terminal emulators that support ANSI escape codes.

Note that this is not supported by the C language, but is widely supported by terminal emulators.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* ANSI Escape Sequences */
#define ESC  "\x1B"
#define CLS  ESC"[2J"
#define HOME  ESC"[H"

void clear_to_top(void) {
    printf(CLS);
    printf(HOME);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(void) {
    clear_to_top();
    puts("Starting from the top....");
}
```

Comment: thanks, this solution works for me and no external library is required

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the terminal screen and set the cursor to the top left corner by printing a `'\f'` byte to the terminal. eg: `putchar('\f')`, but remember that `stdout` is line buffered by default so you may need to flush the buffered output with `fflush(stdout)`.

`'\f'` stands for *form feed*, a command used to eject the page from the printer, and is interpreted by terminals as a *clear screen* command.

The byte value in ASCII is 12, also referred to as <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd>.

Some terminals handle it this way, but it seems neither the OP's ConEmu, nor macOS' Terminal or iTerm2, nor most X-Windows terminals... So this is definitely not a solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm using ConEmu and when ssh into my linux server, print `'\f'` gives me a [female sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334370/escape-sequence-f-form-feed-what-exactly-is-it)...

Comment: Printing `'\f'` to the terminal and calling `fflush` did not seem to have any effect for me in either Konsole or Xfce Terminal on Debian Linux.

Comment: @adabsurdum: I guess I was out of line!  FF is handled like LF, it merely causes a line to be skipped.  I even implemented this in the Quick Emacs shell buffer which acts like an ANSI terminal.  Shame on me.  I shall delete this answer tonight.

Comment: @chqrlie -- I always enjoy reading your answers, and I usually learn some things. When I saw your proposed `'\f'` solution I hadn't heard of it, so I tried it unsuccessfully. That is what inspired me to write my answer since I knew it was possible with ANSI escape codes (which of course isn't portable, either). I only tried your solution with two terminal emulators, but I suspected that there were some terminals in which `'\f'` would work.

Comment: @adabsurdum: I honestly cannot remember where I got this idea.  It is difficult to test remotely from my macbook in a crowded ferry terminal... It seems logical, but I don't know where it works.