# Carriage return issue decoding Base64 from Java and sending to browser

Tags: java, encoding, base64, carriage-return

I have a servlet that has resized and encoded an image into base64. I encode it like this

```
BufferedImage newBuf = .. a bufferedImage...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, sImgFormat, baos);
baos.flush();
imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

I then encode this into base64 to send to the browser like this

```
sun.misc.BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String sEncImage = "data:image/jpg;base64," + encoder.encodeBuffer(imageInBytes);
```

The browser will receive the encoding and it works except for the carriage returns, ("\n") embedded consistently within the string which corrupts the image. When I remove the carriage returns the image is fine. Is there a way to generate the encoding without the carriage returns. Or must I filter it out myself before sending it back ?

(I am using J2SE 1.4.2 and need to continue to do so)

Comment: I need to send base64 text to browser. HTML5 at other end

Comment: \n isn't a carriage return character, it is a line feed. \r is the carriage return.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the sun.misc.Base64encoder is chunking the output. 
I wouldn't use sun.misc classes as it restricts your code to Oracle JVMs (for example, it would work in IBM Websphere). I'd use the commons [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html) encoder or [Base64OutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64OutputStream.html).

Comment: When you mean by "chunking" it's putting a "\n" delimiter after each "chunk". So the commons Base64 would provide a "pure" base64 conversion ?

Comment: sun.misc classes don't exist in non-oracle JVMs while the commons Base64 works in all JVMs. Yes chunking puts a carriage return after every 76 characters.

Comment: Ok. Just to confirm, the commons codec is compatible from 1.4?

Comment: As per http://commons.apache.org/codec/, Commons codec 1.4 and 1.5 are compatible with JDK 1.4

Comment: So does the commons ```Base64``` not insert ```\n``` ?

Comment: As per the [docs](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html), `encodeBase64` doesn't and `encodeBase64Chunked` does insert line feeds.

Comment: Strange how the default capability in sun.misc.Base64Encoder would chunk. Looking at it in "pure" data translation terms, it corrupts the data by default. I suppose the output was intended for VT220 terminals ?