# What's the difference between \r\n and \n

Tags: character-encoding, control-characters

In Terminal it seems like no difference between the two

`echo -en 'first\r\nsecond'` and `echo -en 'first\n\second'`

but in the code without \r it doesn't work

```
echo -en 'GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\n\r\n' | nc localhost 9292
```

works, but

```
echo -en 'GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\n\n' | nc localhost 9292
```

doesn't

anyone can explain why it is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some applications can handle both \r\n (a.k.a. CRLF, carriage return line feed) and \n (a.k.a. LF, line feed) equivalently as newline sequences. Your terminal is an example.

The [HTTP/1.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) dictates that HTTP header lines always end with CRLF. So, an HTTP server which adheres to the specification (such as the one you're running on localhost:9292) will not interpret LF by itself as a valid HTTP header line termination sequence.