# line-counting, how to process CRLF?

Tags: c++, windows, carriage-return, linefeed

I'm writing a simple wrapper-class for scanning a stream of characters character-by-character.

```
Scanner scanner("Hi\r\nYou!");
const char* current =  scanner.cchar();
while (*current != 0) {
    printf("Char: %d, Column: %d, Line: %d\n", *current, scanner.column(), scanner.line());
    current = scanner.read();
}

C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>g++ main.cpp -o main.exe
C:\Users\niklas\Desktop>main.exe
Char: 72, Column: 0, Line: 0
Char: 105, Column: 1, Line: 0
Char: 13, Column: 0, Line: 1
Char: 10, Column: 0, Line: 2
Char: 89, Column: 1, Line: 2
Char: 111, Column: 2, Line: 2
Char: 117, Column: 3, Line: 2
Char: 33, Column: 4, Line: 2
```

This example already shows the problem I'm stuck with. One can interpret `\r` as a new-line, as well as `\n`. But together (`\r\ n`) they are just a *single* new-line as well!

The function that processes line- and column-numbers is this:

```
void _processChar(int revue) {
    char chr = _source[_position];
    if (chr == '\r' or chr == '\n') {
        _line += revue;
        _column = 0;
    }
    else {
        _column += revue;
    }
}
```

Sure, I could just look at the character that appears *after* the character at the current position, **but**: I *do not* check for NULL-termination on the source because I want to be able to process character streams that may contain `\0` characters without being terminated at that point.

How can I handle CRLF this way?

**Edit 1**: DOH! This seems to be working fine. Is this safe in any case or do I have an issue somewhere?

```
void _processChar(int revue) {
    char chr = _source[_position];

    bool is_newline = (chr == '\r' or chr == '\n');
    if (chr == '\n' and _position > 0) {
        is_newline = (_source[_position - 1] != '\r');
    }

    if (is_newline) {
        _line += revue;
        _column = 0;
    }
    else {
        _column += revue;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just ignore `\r` and count `\n` as a newline. All modern computers do it this way (including Windows and Mac).

Comment: Windows notepad does *only* interpret `\r\n` as new-line (on Windows 7 here)

Comment: @Seth “Be conservative in what you produce, liberal in what you accept.”

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That would give you a (very) wrong answer on systems that use only \r though.

Comment: @Mehrdad which systems are those?

Comment: @NiklasR It doesn't really matter what notepad does.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328/541686

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems legit to me:

```
void _processChar() {
    char chr = _source[_position];

    // Treat CRLF as a single new-line
    bool is_newline = (chr == '\r' or chr == '\n');
    if (chr == '\n' and _position > 0) {
        is_newline = (_source[_position - 1] != '\r');
    }

    if (is_newline) {
        _line += 1;
        _column = 0;
    }
    else {
        _column += 1;
    }
}
```

At the point where a `\n` is processed, it checks whether the *previous* character is carriage return (`\r`). If so, the line-number is *not* increased.

Also, before it checks the previous character, it tests whether *there is actually* a previous character (`and _position > 0`).

*I've removed the* `int revue` *argument as I just noticed that what I wanted to achieve is not possible they way I tried to achieve it. I wanted to be able to go backwards in the source, but I can not retrieve the column-number from the previous line then.*

Answer (score 3):

Most modern systems handle `\n` as the the newline for the current target platform so all of that should happen automatically for you if you just check for `\n`.

Comment: That depends on what you want and what and where the text is coming from.  The i/o systems in C and C++ will translate the host's newline sequence to `'\n'`.  If you got the text some other way, or if you're trying to count lines in a file that's not native to the host system, you cannot rely on that translation.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to keep state inside your stream wrapper -- a stateless wrapper, as you've noticed, simply *cannot* do this, because every output can (by definition) depend on the previous output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `_processChar` doesn’t appear to increment the stream read position. Once you change that, you can implement the full newline check:

```
void _processChar(int revue) {
    char chr = _source[_position];
    if (chr != '\r' and chr != '\n') {
        _column += revue;
        return;
    }
    if (if chr == '\r' and _source[_position + 1] == '\n')
        ++_position;
    _line += revue;
    _column = 0;
}
```

Comment: `_processChar` is not intended to increment the position. :) As stated above, I want to be able to process *not* null-terminated strings as well. The memory at `_source[_position + 1]` may already be *not part* of the parsed source. Stopping the scanning-process at the correct point is left to the user of the class.

Comment: @NiklasR Effectively, you then *cannot* handle it, since `"\r\n"` simply isn’t a single-char token. You need to change your logic to handle it.