# How to remove a newline from a string in Bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have the following variable.

```
echo "|$COMMAND|"
```

which returns

```
|
REBOOT|
```

How can I remove that first newline?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

## In string, character replacement / deletion

### Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there are some *bashisms*:

The `tr` command could be replaced by `${parameter/pattern/string}` with `ANSI C standard`  *bashism*:

```bash
COMMAND=$'\nREBOOT\r   \n'
echo "|${COMMAND}|"
|
   OOT
|

echo "|${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}|"
|REBOOT   |

echo "|${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n ']}|"
|REBOOT|
```

See *Parameter Expansion* and *ANSI C standard* in bash's man page:

```bash
man bash | sed '/^$/{ x;\|parameter/pattern/string|{s/^\n*//;p};s/.*//;h;};H;d'
```

> ```
>      ${parameter/pattern/string}
>      ${parameter//pattern/string}
>      ${parameter/#pattern/string}
>      ${parameter/%pattern/string}
>             Pattern  substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a
>             pattern just as in pathname  expansion.   Parameter  is  ex‐
>             panded and the longest match of pattern against its value is
>             replaced with string.  string undergoes tilde expansion, pa‐
>             rameter  and  variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, com‐
>             mand and process substitution, and quote removal.  The match
>             is  performed using the rules described under Pattern Match‐
>             ing below.  In the first form above, only the first match is
>             replaced.  If there are two slashes separating parameter and
>             pattern (the second form above), all matches of pattern  are
>             replaced  with  string.   If  pattern  is preceded by # (the
>             third form above), it must match at the beginning of the ex‐
>             panded value of parameter.  If pattern is preceded by % (the
>             fourth form above), it must match at the end of the expanded
>             value  of  parameter.   If  the expansion of string is null,
>             matches of pattern are deleted.  If string is null,  matches
>             of  pattern  are  deleted and the / following pattern may be
>             omitted.
> ```

```bash
man bash | sed '/^$/{ x;/ANSI \+C \+standard/{s/^\n*//;p};s/.*//;h;};H;d'
man bash | sed '/^$/{ x;/ANSI[[:space:]]\+C[[:space:]]\+standard/{s/^\n*//;p};s/.*//;h;};H;d'
```

> ```
>      Character  sequences of the form $'string' are treated as a special
>      variant of single quotes.  The sequence  expands  to  string,  with
>      backslash-escaped characters in string replaced as specified by the
>      ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present,  are  de‐
>      coded as follows:
>             \a     alert (bell)
>             \b     backspace
>             \e
>             \E     an escape character
>             \f     form feed
>             \n     new line
>             \r     carriage return
>             \t     horizontal tab
>             \v     vertical tab
>             \\     backslash
>             \'     single quote
>             \"     double quote
>             \?     question mark
>             \nnn   the  eight-bit  character  whose  value  is the octal
>                    value nnn (one to three octal digits)
>             \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the  hexadeci‐
>                    mal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>             \uHHHH the  Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is
>                    the hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>             \UHHHHHHHH
>                    the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value  is
>                    the hexadecimal value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex dig‐
>                    its)
>             \cx    a control-x character
> ```

#### Further...

As asked by @AlexJordan, this will suppress **all** specified characters. So what if `$COMMAND` do contain spaces...

```
COMMAND=$'         \n        RE BOOT      \r           \n'
echo "|$COMMAND|"
|
           BOOT      
|

read -r COMMAND <<<"${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}"
echo "|$COMMAND|"
|RE BOOT|
```

##### Explanation

Answering [Vulwsztyn's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-a-newline-from-a-string-in-bash/19347380?noredirect=1#comment134857740_19347380):

> Why does this work when the pattern is empty?

In `${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n ']}` :

- The 1st slashe `/` mean: ***Pattern substitution*** (following  `${parameter/pattern/string}` syntax)
- The *`pattern`* is `/[$'\r\n ']`, begin with `/` then *all  matches of pattern are replaced with `string`*
- Then, the *replacement `string`* is empty (as there a no second `/` followed by any *`string`*...).

##### 1 step more further

If you try to replace *`nothing`* by something, for sample two consecutive spaces (then you could add two more spaces **after** replaced string in order to balance output):

```
echo "|${COMMAND//*()/  }  |"
|  R  E     B  O  O  T  |
```

### Avoid *fork* to `tr` for single string!

Let compare:

```bash
COMMAND=$'\nREBOOT\r   \n'
echo ${COMMAND@Q}
$'\nREBOOT\r \n'

COMMAND=$(echo $COMMAND|tr -d '\n\t\r ')
echo ${COMMAND@Q}
'REBOOT'
```

Then

```bash
time for i in {1..1000};do
    COMMAND=$'\nREBOOT\r   \n'
    COMMAND=$(echo $COMMAND|tr -d '\n\t\r ')
done;echo ${COMMAND@Q}

real    0m2.785s
user    0m2.296s
sys     0m0.774s
'REBOOT'
```

With

```bash
COMMAND=$'\nREBOOT\r   \n'
COMMAND="${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n ']}"
echo ${COMMAND@Q}

time for i in {1..1000};do
    COMMAND=$'\nREBOOT\r   \n'
    COMMAND="${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n ']}"
done;echo ${COMMAND@Q}

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.004s
'REBOOT'
```

Doing 1'000 forks to `tr` take more than 2700ms on my host, while same job is done in 6ms ( **464.2x faster!!** ) by using *built-in* bash *Parameter Expansion*!!

Note: In fact: `var=$(echo | tr x y)` implie two forks, not only one! By using following syntax, you will avoid 1 (x1000) fork, so this could be a little quicker:

```bash
time for i in {1..1000};do
    COMMAND=$'\nREBOOT\r   \n'
    COMMAND=$( tr -d '\n\t\r ' <<<"$COMMAND" )
done;echo ${COMMAND@Q}

real    0m2.181s
user    0m1.590s
sys     0m0.566s
'REBOOT'
```

But still a lot overkill compared to the *pure bash* method.

Comment: This is the way to strip linefeeds from a variable in BASH. Other answers are needlessly invoking an extra TR process. BTW, it has the added benefit of removing ending spaces!

Comment: Note that it also removes *internal* spaces from a string as well... `COMMAND="RE BOOT"; echo "|${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n ']}|"` returns `|REBOOT|`

Comment: @AlexJordan Yes, it's a *wanted feature*:  You could whipe the space after `\n` to prevent this: `COMMAND="RE BOOT"; echo "|${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}|"` will return `|RE BOOT|`.

Comment: Fair enough - but I was trying to just trim the trailing spaces: `"RE BOOT        \r"` turns into `"REBOOT"`, which is not what I wanted. Thought @ingyhere's comment was incomplete, so I dropped a comment!

Comment: @AlexJordan Answer edited: I've added a clean way to strip bounding spaces.

Comment: How is the pattern working in `${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}`? I thought `${COMMAND//[\t\r\n]}` would simply work, but it didn't. What is the `$` symbol for and the single quotes too?

Comment: Regarding the $'' syntax, that's [ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (mentioned in wjordans answer).

Comment: In VScode you can convert the line endings for the file from CRLF to LF and save it

Comment: @AlexJordan My answer to you're [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-a-newline-from-a-string-in-bash/19347380#comment59718553_19347380) was modified: Using `read`, there is no need to use extglob anymore.

Comment: Why does this work when the pattern is empty?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34789399/7195666

Comment: @Vulwsztyn Answer edited regarding your comment/question.

Answer (score 125):

Clean your variable by removing all the linefeeds:

```
COMMAND=$(echo $COMMAND|tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: Doesn't that strip linefeeds? Shouldn't it be `tr -d '\r'` instead?

Comment: Echoing an uncommented variable removes all IFS characters (newline, space, tab by default). So if you're going to do this, you should be aware that *all* IFS characters are dropped, and you don't need the `tr`. Simply `COMMAND=$(echo $COMMAND)` will give a similar effect. Which is, presumably, devil spawn as it invokes a new process, but it's still pretty short and sweet for the human's eyes and if you have a second or two to spare in your life you may be willing to take the hit :-) .

Comment: I've updated the question to say "linefeed", as its example did show that it was a linefeed, not a carriage return. This answer is still correct, but should maybe be updated to say "linefeed" instead of "carriage return"?

Comment: should have been the accepted answer combined with bash specific `${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}`

Comment: @MikeS `+1` for noticing the antipattern `echo $COMMAND` (missing quotes). But _it's an antipattern and shouldn't be used_ since it will also expand glob characters if there are any (e.g., `*`, or `[...]` or `?`). So never use an unquoted expansion, _unless your variable is in fact a glob that you want to actually expand._

Answer (score 108):

```
echo "|$COMMAND|"|tr '\n' ' '
```

will replace the newline (in POSIX/Unix it's not a carriage return) with a space.

To be honest I would think about switching away from bash to something more sane though. Or avoiding generating this malformed data in the first place.

Hmmm, this seems like it could be a horrible security hole as well, depending on where the data is coming from.

Comment: The date is coming from a curl request which is on the same server, How would i go about putting that into a new var ? newvar=$(echo "|$COMMAND|"|tr '\n' ' ')

Comment: Yes. But please tell me you're not allowing arbitrary people to reboot your server remotely without a password...

Comment: Why did you not use `tr -d '\n'` for *dropping* instead of *replace by a space*

Comment: Please whipe useless pipes! Use `tr '\n' ' ' <<< "|$COMMAND|"` instead of `echo ... | ...`

Comment: @F.Hauri: or useless tr's: `"|${COMMAND//$'\n'}|"`

Comment: @rici: It already was my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19347380/1765658) ;-)

Comment: @F.Hauri: Fair enough. I just didn't see what privileged pipe-removal over process-removal. Particularly since echo is builtin, so there's not a lot of difference between the echo and the <<<

Comment: @rici: Try this: `time for i in {0..1000};do wc -c >/dev/null <<<blah;done` then this: `time for i in {0..1000};do echo blah | wc -c >/dev/null ;done` On my system, first take ~1.4 secs and second syntax take ~3.2 secs.

Comment: tr '\n' ' ' <<< "|$COMMAND|" by F.Hauri - Worked fine.

Comment: Less efficient than substring subtitution in F. Hauri's answer, I think?

Answer (score 15):

Using `bash`:

```
echo "|${COMMAND/$'\n'}|"
```

<sup>(Note that the control character in this question is a 'newline' (`\n`), not a carriage return (`\r`); the latter would have output `REBOOT|` on a single line.)</sup>

#### Explanation

Uses the Bash [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) `${parameter/pattern/string}`:

> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern* against its value is replaced with *string*. [...] If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the */* following *pattern* may be omitted.

Also uses the `$''` [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) construct to specify a newline as `$'\n'`. Using a newline directly would work as well, though less pretty:

```
echo "|${COMMAND/
}|"
```

#### Full example

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="$'\n'REBOOT"
echo "|${COMMAND/$'\n'}|"
# Outputs |REBOOT|
```

Or, using newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND="
REBOOT"
echo "|${COMMAND/
}|"
# Outputs |REBOOT|
```

Answer (score 12):

Adding answer to show example of stripping multiple characters including \r using tr and using sed.
And illustrating using hexdump.

In my case I had found that a command ending with awk print of the last item `|awk '{print $2}'` in the line included a carriage-return \r as well as quotes.

I used `sed 's/["\n\r]//g'` to strip both the carriage-return and quotes.

I could also have used `tr -d '"\r\n'`.

Interesting to note `sed -z` is needed if one wishes to remove \n line-feed chars.

```
$ COMMAND=$'\n"REBOOT"\r   \n'

$ echo "$COMMAND" |hexdump -C
00000000  0a 22 52 45 42 4f 4f 54  22 0d 20 20 20 0a 0a     |."REBOOT".   ..|

$ echo "$COMMAND" |tr -d '"\r\n' |hexdump -C
00000000  52 45 42 4f 4f 54 20 20  20                       |REBOOT   |

$ echo "$COMMAND" |sed 's/["\n\r]//g' |hexdump -C
00000000  0a 52 45 42 4f 4f 54 20  20 20 0a 0a              |.REBOOT   ..|

$ echo "$COMMAND" |sed -z 's/["\n\r]//g' |hexdump -C
00000000  52 45 42 4f 4f 54 20 20  20                       |REBOOT   |
```

And this is relevant:
[What are carriage return, linefeed, and form feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed)

- CR == \r == 0x0d
- LF == \n == 0x0a

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me was `echo $testVar | tr "\n" " "`

Where  testVar contained my variable/script-output

Answer (score 6):

Use this bashism if you don't want to spawn processes like (tr, sed or awk) for such a simple task. Bash can do that alone:

```
COMMAND=${COMMAND//$'\n'/}
```

From the documentation:

```
${FOO//from/to} Replace all
${FOO/from/to}  Replace first match
```

Comment: You're posting 9 years after the answer was posted with those very bashisms, with excellent examples, with awesome pointers to the documentation. F. Hauri had the best answer in 2013, and this one adds nothing to it while leaving out some nice extras. Sorry, -1.

Comment: @MikeS Sorry, if we want to write effective bash scripts, it is important to use the least possible amount of external binary executions. That means, we need to handle things with the internal bash meachnisms as possible. This is the first and only answer what does it. Many active bash users do not see any bad in the external calls, others yes. This dualism is very characteristic also on the Unix SE. If you do not have a strong affection _for_ calling the most possible external binaries, I think this answer is not so bad even on your opinion.

Comment: @peterh do you not see F. Hauri's answer? He uses the same construct. For example: `CLEANED=${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}` . I didn't downvote because of its effectiveness in writing bash scripts, I downvoted because it shows up before F. Hauri's answer, which is more complete and includes pointers to the man pages and so on. It adds nothing new.

Comment: @MikeS Well I overlooked it because its complexity. I searched for a quick solution only with internal commands. It is good to you if you can make a living by shell scripts.

Comment: @MikeS Thanks for this. I was getting confused on F. Hauri's answer. You rock!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using bash with the extglob option enabled, you can remove just the trailing whitespace via:

```
shopt -s extglob
COMMAND=$'\nRE BOOT\r   \n'
echo "|${COMMAND%%*([$'\t\r\n '])}|"
```

This outputs:

```
|
RE BOOT|
```

Or replace %% with ## to replace just the leading whitespace.

Comment: This worked like a charm with some weird output I got from a docker command. Much thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `echo -n "|$COMMAND|"`.

`$ man echo`

> `-n` do not output the trailing newline

Comment: But at least one of the newlines under concern was not at the end. So this doesn't help.

Comment: With all due respect: have you already tried my solution and checked whether or not it solved the original question?

Comment: No, because the man page is quite clear: -n does not output the trailing newline. That's it, no more no less. If there's an embedded newline- which there is in the original question- then echo -n won't help. I did try it just now, and it behaves exactly as described. Embedded newlines remain; it does not "remove that first newline" which is what the original question asked. In bash, btw.

Comment: Well, I got your point. When I run the command I suggested, the output is the same when you remove the first, even though the command I suggested is not intended for that. I believe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

To address one possible root of the actual issue, there is a chance you are sourcing a crlf file.

CRLF Example:

.env (crlf)

```
VARIABLE_A="abc"
VARIABLE_B="def"
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source .env
echo "$VARIABLE_A"
echo "$VARIABLE_B"
echo "$VARIABLE_A $VARIABLE_B"
```

Returns:

```
abc
def
 def
```

If however you convert to LF:

.env (lf)

```
VARIABLE_A="abc"
VARIABLE_B="def"
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source .env
echo "$VARIABLE_A"
echo "$VARIABLE_B"
echo "$VARIABLE_A $VARIABLE_B"
```

Returns:

```
abc
def
abc def
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I've been pulling my hairs on this for a while wondering why variable substitution was messing my string. Was using a CRLF file on linux...

Answer (score 0):

Note that the shell already does that for you if you pass `$COMMAND` as a parameter instead of a string.

So you can try this:

```
COMMAND="a
   b
   c"

echo $COMMAND
```

To add the pipes, you can just use the quotes and no spaces like so:

```
echo "|"$COMMAND"|"
```

works just fine and it's a tad simpler than the other solutions. It also works with just `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score -3):

Grep can be used to filter out any blank lines. This is useful if you have several lines of data and want to remove any empty.

```
echo "$COMMAND" | grep .
```