# WP-Cli Multisite Reports

Tags: wordpress, bash, wp-cli

I've got a multisite install and wp-cli set up and working. Optimally, what I'd need is a script to run that will generate a list of all of the sites on the multisite install along with the name of the active theme.

I can figure out how to run this on a single-site basis, but really what I need is the ability to generate the list.

We've got about 400+ sites within our network, growing weekly. Has anyone tackled this problem yet?

---

Update: I've got this mostly working now, though I feel like this could be better optimized.

I'm saving this as **list_active_themes.sh** and am outputting it as a JSON file by running `sh list_active_themes.sh > active_themes.json`.

The last piece is to remove the trailing comma that is the result of the 9th line below-- and me not knowing how to count the returned `site` results in order to do an if statement to not output the comma if it is the final one in the for loop.

Here's my code:

```
echo "{"
for site in $(wp site list --domain=sample.domain.com --field=url --quiet)
    do
        echo -e '\t"site":{'
            printf '\t\t"url":"%s",\n' "$site"
            echo -e '\t\t"theme":"'|tr '\n' ''
            wp theme list --status=active --field=name --url=$site|tr '\n' ''
            echo '"'
        echo -e '\n\t},'
    done
echo "}"
```

Comment: I'm just a bash guy, no idea of wp-cli. But if you can do something about a single site, you can surely do the same thing with multiple sites in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the task in two basic operations:

1. List all sites in a multisite install: [`wp site list`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/site/list/)
2. Get a list of themes: [`wp theme list`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/theme/list/)

With this information we can get a list of all site URLs in the network:

```
wp site list --field=url
```

Knowing the site URL, we're able to list the associated **active** theme:

```
wp theme list --status=active --url="<site_url>"
```

Now we can setup a basic bash script to loop through each site in the network and get the associated theme:

```
#!/bin/bash
for site in $(wp site list --field=url)
do
    wp theme list --status=active --url=$site
done
```

Save this to a file (e.g. `list_active_themes.sh`) and run it from the terminal:

```
sh list_active_themes.sh
```

---

So now let's return our own custom list containing site URL + theme name with a structure like:

```
Site: <site_url> Theme: <theme_name>
```

The according bash script could look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for site in $(wp site list --field=url)
do
    echo Site:|tr '\n' ' '
    echo $site|tr '\n' ' '
    echo Theme:|tr '\n' ' '
    wp theme list --status=active --field=name --url=$site
done
```

(The expression [`|tr '\n' ' '`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19345906/1815847) replaces the newline with a space, [`|tr -d '\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/dirty-variable-remove-carriage-return/19345906#comment28664440_19345906) completely drops the newline.)

---

**Update:**

Using `--format=count` option will return the total number of sites; we can use this value as a condition within the loop and generate a JSON-like structure (as suggested from your comment):

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=1
SITES=$(wp site list --format=count)
echo "{"
for site in $(wp site list --field=url)
    do
        echo '\t"site":{'
            printf '\t\t"url":"%s",\n' "$site"
            echo '\t\t"theme":"'|tr -d '\n'
            wp theme list --status=active --field=name --url=$site|tr -d '\n'
            echo '"'
        echo '\n\t}'|tr -d '\n'
        if (($COUNTER != $SITES)); then
            echo ,
        fi
        COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
    done
echo "\n}"
```

The script above will return something like this:

```
{
    "site":{
        "url":"http://site_one.dev/",
        "theme":"theme_one"
    },
    "site":{
        "url":"http://site_one.dev/",
        "theme":"theme_two"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I added more to the question above