# What is the meaning of `//` in Bash parameter expansions?

Tags: bash

What does `//,/` mean in this command?

```
echo ${foo//,/}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `bash(1)` man page (http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion. Parameter is expanded and the longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with string. If pattern begins with `/`, all matches of pattern are replaced with string. Normally only the first match is replaced. If pattern begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter. If pattern begins with `%`, it must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter. If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the `/` following pattern may be omitted. If parameter is `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

That is, `${something//,/}` is expanded to the `$something` with all the occurrences of `,` removed.

Comment: OK - i get you: "If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are replaced   with  string.   "