# Bash command on a variable

Tags: bash, syntax, parameter-expansion

What does the following bash command do?

```
"${ctp// /}"
```

I want to check whether a variable is composed of an empty string or is all spaces, so that I can assign a default value.

Comment: See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: ...also [replace a string in shell script using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3306054/14122)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It removes any *space* characters.

*Parameter Expansion* expands parameters: `$foo`, `$1`. You can use it to perform string or array operations: `"${file%.mp3}"`, `"${0##*/}"`, `"${files[@]: -4}"`. They should **always** be quoted.
See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 and "Parameter Expansion" in man bash.
Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

Comment: _raises an eyebrow re: answering a duplicate_

Comment: Do you have the link Charles?

Comment: If you didn't consider the linked duplicate at the time of my earlier comment acceptable, how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34789149/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-bash-parameter-expansions ?

Comment: Sure. And an eyebrow raise is not a downvote (which is what I'd do if I thought this was a bad answer). That said, what I do personally when I answer a question that looks off-topic is set the community-wiki flag so it doesn't look like I'm trying to farm rep by playing at the edge of the rules.