# How to display a file with multiple lines as a single string with escape chars (\n)

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, io-redirection

In bash, how I can display the content of a file with multiple lines as a single string where new lines appears as `\n`.

Example:

```
$ echo "line 1
line 2" >> file.txt
```

I need to get the content as this `"line 1\nline2"` with bash commands.

I tried using a combinations of `cat/printf/echo` with no success.

Comment: Possible XY problem: *why* do you think you need this?

Comment: do  you really want the dbl-quotes in your output? Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use bash's `printf` to get something close:

```
$ printf "%q" "$(< file.txt)"
$'line1\nline2'
```

and in `bash` 4.4 there is a new parameter expansion operator to produce the same:

```
$ foo=$(<file.txt)
$ echo "${foo@Q}"
$'line1\nline2'
```

Comment: Works great! Only thing is a double quote is missing just before the dollar sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file.txt 
line 1
line 2
$ paste -s -d '~' file.txt | sed 's/~/\\n/g'
line 1\nline 2
```

You can use `paste` command to paste all the lines of the serially with delimiter say `~` and replace all `~` with `\n` with a `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

> Without '\n' after file 2, you need to use echo -n

```
echo -n "line 1
line 2" > file.txt

od -cv file.txt
0000000   l   i   n   e       1  \n   l   i   n   e       2

sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' file.txt
line 1\nline 2
```

> With '\n' after line 2

```
echo "line 1
line 2" > file.txt

od -cv file.txt
0000000   l   i   n   e       1  \n   l   i   n   e       2  \n

sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g' file.txt
line 1\nline 2\n
```

Answer (score 0):

This tools may display character codes also:

```
$ hexdump -v -e '/1 "%_c"' file.txt ; echo
line 1\nline 2\n

$ od -vAn -tc file.txt 
   l   i   n   e       1  \n   l   i   n   e       2  \n
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try piping a string from stdin or file and trim the desired pattern...

try this:

```
cat file|tr '\n' ' '
```

where file is the file name with the \n. this will return a string with all the text in a single line.

if you want to write the result to a file just redirect the result of the command, like this.

```
cat file|tr '\n' ' ' >> file2
```

here is another example:
[How to remove carriage return from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/dirty-variable-remove-carriage-return)

Comment: the question is asking to get `\n` not a space as "line separator"