# How to delimit based multiple occurrence of the same character in the same String

Tags: shell

I'm trying to split strings based on *"##"* characters. The challenge is the number of occurrences of *"#"* is not always 2. I can get up to 5 occurrences at times.

If it was a static occurrences like *'##'* or *'###'* I would have used:

```
IFS="##" read -ra var1 <<< "$var"
```

Here is my string:

```
Strin1##String2###String3##String4#####String5
```

Currently I'm following `IFS="##"`, later remove all the occurrences of *'#'*. However I'm looking for a code way to support this.

Comment: Please clarify whether `var=foo####bar` represents an array of *two* items, or *three*, (the middle item a blank string).

Comment: i do not have any control over the variable var. It can be array of more than two items.

Comment: It's a hypothetical question.  **Suppose** that `var=foo####bar`.  Now, *supposing* that, please tell us if `$var1` ought to have *two* items, or *three*.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has [*parameter transformation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732193/bash-how-to-use-operator-parameter-expansion-parameteroperator) operators to help debug problems like this:

```
var='Strin1##String2###String3##String4#####String5'
IFS="##" read -ra var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 <<< "$var"
echo ${var1[@]@A}
```

...which uses the `A`*ssignment* operator to print a `declare` statement showing what's *really* in the array `$var1`:

```
declare -a var1=([0]="Strin1" [1]="" [2]="String2" [3]="" [4]="" [5]="String3" [6]="" [7]="String4" [8]="" [9]="" [10]="" [11]="" [12]="String5")
```

There's *thirteen* items, which corresponds to each "side" of the *twelve* `#`s in the `$var` string.  This is because the `$IFS` variable does not understand user-assigned strings, it only looks at those individual characters in a string.  So `IFS="#######"` and `IFS="##"` and `IFS="#"` are all equivalent, at least so far as `read` is concerned.

The simplest fix is to first run `$var` through `tr`'s *squeeze* function to remove the repeating `#`s:

```
var='Strin1##String2###String3##String4#####String5'
IFS="#" read -ra var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 <<< "$(tr -s '#' <<< "$var")"
echo ${var1[@]@A}
```

Which outputs:

```
declare -a var1=([0]="Strin1" [1]="String2" [2]="String3" [3]="String4" [4]="String5")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex on IFS

```
IFS="##[#]*" read -ra var1 <<< "Strin1##String2###String3##String4#####String5"
```

When you print var1 array, you'll get

```
Strin1 String2 String3 String4 String5
```

Comment: That doesn't work for the reason you think it does. `IFS` specifies a collection of characters; ordering and repetition makes no difference at all. If you specify `IFS=abc`, then `abc123abc` behaves just the same as `aaa123aaa` or `cba123cba` or `a123b`.

Comment: ...so, all you're doing with `IFS='##[#]*'` is telling `[` and `*` to be special in addition to `#`.

Comment: See the above assertions demonstrated in the transcript at https://ideone.com/nCfm03