# bash parameter transformation gives bad substitution

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I always get a `bad substitution` error when I use Parameter Transformation in a script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
abc=abc
echo ${abc@U}
```

result

```
line 3: ${abc#U}: bad substitution
```

However, it works fine in interactive mode

```
> abc=abc
> echo ${abc@U}
ABC
```

I'm aware of the
[Bash: How to use operator parameter expansion ${parameter@operator}?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732193/bash-how-to-use-operator-parameter-expansion-parameteroperator)
question but there is no answer.

How can I use parameter transformation in a script?

Comment: What version is `/usr/bin/env bash`? What version is your interactive bash?

Comment: `/usr/bin/env bash` 5.0.17, interactive bash 5.1.4(1)

Answer (score 0):

Need bash version 5.1 or greater

Comment: Check the [release notes](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES): transformations `U`, `u`, `L`, `K` were added in version 5.1

Comment: To uppercase in 4.0+, you can use `declare -u abc` or `${abc^^}`