# In bash, why not remove line breaks using echo?

Tags: bash, echo

After reading [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-a-newline-from-a-string-in-bash), which suggests removing "line breaks" (understood as `\n` not `\r\n`) in bash using "c-style strings" (e.g., ${COMMAND//[$'\t\r\n']}), why not use `echo` instead? In other words:

```
foo=$'Apple\nBanana\nCherry\n'
echo $foo
Apple Banana Cherry
```

OR

```
foo=$(ls -1)
echo $foo
Jenkinsfile README.md exclude_contents install_kit.sh packaging
```

Does this cause unintentional side-effects or other problems? If the requirement is to remove line breaks, it seems simpler than `${foo//[$'\n']}`

Note: I'm aware that `echo "$foo"` retains the line breaks and that if `foo` contains `\r\n` then `echo "$foo"` won't display everything on a single line.

Comment: `echo` doesn't have a [standard behavior](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219268/how-to-add-new-lines-when-using-echo#answer-219274) you can rely upon when it comes to handling of newline. The shell method is more definitive.

Comment: See the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) to appreciate just how unreliable/nonportable its behavior *is*. Even `echo`'s own specification document suggests that `printf` be used instead.

Comment: [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) is also relevant.

Comment: Doing something like `tr '\n' ' ' <<< "$foo"` is only slightly longer, and without the nasty side effects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `echo $foo` will cause unexpected side-effects.

#### Issues with pathname expansion

Consider a directory with these four files:

```
$ ls
f*  factor  fo?  foo
```

Now, observe that `echo $foo` produces a list of eight file names:

```
$ foo=$(ls -1)
$ echo $foo
f* factor fo? foo factor fo? foo foo
```

This is because the unquoted `$foo` in `echo $foo` is subjected not just to *word splitting* (which is what eliminates the newlines) but also to *pathname expansion*.

If we use *pattern substitution* inside double quotes, however, we get the correct file list:

```
$ echo "${foo//$'\n'/ }"
f* factor fo? foo
```

#### Issues with bash's echo

As [@lurker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/980550/lurker) pointed out, `echo` can act in surprising ways.

Consider a directory with three files:

```
$ ls
-e  \none  \text
```

Now, try:

```
$ foo=$(ls -1)
$ echo $foo

one     ext
```

As you can see, the file names were mangled.  This is because `echo` interpreted the file name `-e` not as a file name but as an option, the one that turns on interpretation of escape sequences.  Thus, the file name whose characters are backslash-n-o-n-e becomes newline-one. and the file name whose characters are backslash-t-e-x-t becomes tab-ext.

Bash's echo command is not compatible with [POSIX's `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for which `-e` is treated as text to be printed.  Thus code relying on `echo` is not portable.  For this reason, among others, it is often [recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819#65819) that new code use `printf` rather than `echo`.

Comment: ...moreover, even treating `-e` as something other than a string to be printed makes bash's `echo` noncompliant with the POSIX standard (albeit a noncompliant behavior that can be turned off by flipping appropriate runtime or compile-time flags), so even *that* can't be relied on.