# Change directory to Window's user directory in WSL bash script

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to write a script to automate installing some things in WSL and then cloning a repo to the user's home folder in Windows (e.g. C:/Users/Frank/).

To do this I need to get the Windows username (e.g. `Frank`) to know where to `cd` to. I found that I could execute Windows command line commands with `cmd.exe /c '<command>'` and that the command `echo %USERNAME%` outputs the Windows user's username.

This is what I've tried so far:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
USER_NAME=`cmd.exe /c 'echo %USERNAME%'`
cd /mnt/c/Users/$USER_NAME
pwd
```

I get an error that I believe stems from the Windows carriage return characters `\r` which I guess are at the end of the output of `echo %USERNAME%`.

The error:
`ine 3: cd: $'/mnt/c/Users/Frank\r\r\r': No such file or directory`

How can I remove all of the `\r` characters at the end of the output?

Comment: first be sure that your script doesn' contain `\r` chars, `cat -vet myScript`, do you see `^M$` at the end of each line, if yes, then `dos2unix myScript` will fix that. If you still get an error, then try `USER_NAME=\`cmd.exe /c 'echo %USERNAME%' | tr -d '\r'\`` , or you may need `tr -d '015'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your code, edited:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
UNSANITISED_USER_NAME=`cmd.exe /c 'echo %USERNAME%'`
USER_NAME="${UNSANITISED_USER_NAME//$'\r'}"
cd /mnt/c/Users/$USER_NAME
pwd
```

It uses some sort of string formatting to remove all `\r` characters (rather than `tr`, which I couldn't get to work in my testing) adapted from rici's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19345906/11015926).