# Bash Parameter Expansion: What does the Dollar Sign ($) mean in the pattern?

Tags: bash, variables, parameter-expansion

Reference: [How to remove a newline from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-a-newline-from-a-string-in-bash)

I feel a little silly asking this, but when I'm solving a problem, I like to learn about the WHY instead of just copying-and-pasting code I found on the Internet. :-)

I've been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-a-newline-from-a-string-in-bash) and the bash man pages and, for the life of me, I cannot identify in the documentation where this is valid syntax.  However, I run it and it works.

To test, I ran:

```
[me@server ~]# declare -- MY_VAR="some value
> "
```

This creates a variable with \n at the end (i.e. "some value\n").

My goal is to remove the \n at the end.

I know the following code will do it:

```
echo ${MY_VAR//[$'\n']}
```

... what I don't know is WHY.

I've read [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and the section on ${parameter/pattern/string}.  I've also read the referenced section, [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).  Neither tells me that having a dollar sign ($) as the first character in, what I believe to be, a character group ([...]), has any special meaning or what that meaning is.  Also, why does \n need to be enclosed in single-quotes?

I also tried the following variations of the above working command and none of them work:

```
echo ${MY_VAR//['\n']}
echo ${MY_VAR//[$]}
echo ${MY_VAR//['\n'$]}
echo ${MY_VAR//[\n]}
echo ${MY_VAR//[$\n]}
echo ${MY_VAR//['$\n']}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of documentation that can tell me why I need to use the dollar sign ($) and why the \n needs to be enclosed in single-quotes?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer to my own question: [ANSI-C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

`$'string'` is treated specially.  What I believe is happening is that this `$'string'` is being used to pass the special newline character (as well as the tab and carriage return characters in the other post I referenced) back into the character group.

Credit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script