# Unable to send curl output to discord using webhook which is otherwise printing it in my bash terminal

Tags: bash, curl, discord, webhooks

```
status=$(curl -i -s -H "Authorization: token abc123" https://www.some_url.com | awk 'NR==18')

if [ "$status" != 200 ]; then
  echo "$status"
fi
```

The above code is working and echo is printing the output in my console.

But when I use discord webhook, it doesn't send message there and throws following error: **{"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}**

```
webhook=https://discord.com/api/webhooks/abc123

status=$(curl -i -s -H "Authorization: token abc123" https://www.some_url.com | awk 'NR==18')

if [ "$status" != 200 ]; then
  curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"content":"'"$status"'"}' $webhook
fi
```

I can send a normal message through webhook but not this curl output. The output is suppose to be HTML error message.

Even if I change **awk 'NR==18'** to **awk 'NR==1'**, it's not sending even the one line output which is suppose to be something like: **HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a discord bot (webhook) running on a raspberry pi from a bash script, so I think it is the same thing you are looking for

```
sendcontent='{"username": "Botname", "content": "'"${messagearray[@]}"'"}'
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$sendcontent" "$webhookurl"
```

I would suggest the following change to your code:

```
messagearray=($(curl -i -s -H "Authorization: token abc123" https://www.some_url.com | awk 'NR==18'))
```

EDIT:
It seems that there are nasty invisible characters in the curl+awk command return, therefore the above solution needs to be modified as below
(This bash file test with the provided url from comments)

```
#!/bin/bash
webhookurl="https://mywebhook"
messagearray=($(curl -i -s https://www.google.com/ | awk 'NR==1'))
#this next line removes nasty characters that give json errors (keeps only letters, numbers SPACE and -)
message=`echo ${messagearray[@]} | sed 's/[^0-9A-Za-z -]*//g'`;
sendcontent='{"username": "Botname", "content": "'"$message"'"}'
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$sendcontent" "$webhookurl"
```

This successfully sends `HTTP/2 200` in discord

the removal is an adaptation of:
[How to remove a newline from a string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345872/how-to-remove-a-newline-from-a-string-in-bash)

Comment: Thanks @Gerge I'm finally able to send message to discord but only half of it. Like instead of **HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**, it's sending only **HTTP/1.1**. Same for next lines. Instead of **Server: nginx**, only sending **Server:** and so on. Basically it's not sending the text after space. Any solution for that?

Comment: Notice the extra () brackets I suggested to turn it into an array. an array is a set of words separated by spaces and to print all of them you need to use the `${messagearray[@]}` the @ tells it to print all. From your comment I guess you are simply using `$messagearray` like it would be a string, then that results in what you describe only the first part printed

Comment: It would help if you specify the content of ${messagearray[@]} or the output you are trying to pass through, so I can test with it.

Comment: I did change it to `${messagearray[@]}` but then it shows the error `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 200 port 80: Connection refused` and `curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 3: "}`. You could test it for this line: `messagearray=($(curl -i -s https://www.google.com/ | awk 'NR==1'))` which should send the message **HTTP/2 200** to discord.

Comment: It seems I solved it (there might be other nasty characters). I will edit the answer in a minute

Comment: This was a fun hour spent chasing literally nothing because I could not see it. If this solved your problem please mark the answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps. But I'm getting `{"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}` error if I try `NR==12` or any line after like NR==16 or 17... Could you help me with that as well?

Comment: OK, at this point is is easier to specify to only keep letters and numbers in the message. I edited the answer again, this time it removes everything that is not readable text.