# Does C# provide an equivalent to '\n' for denoting a page break?

Tags: c#, string, format

Is there a letter I can locate next to a `'\'` in order to break a page?

Like `\n` is for line break

or `\t` for tab.

Comment: What is displaying this page? There *are* page-break characters, but they may well not be honoured by whatever's displaying your text.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, A Word page for example.

Comment: Well if you're using Word, it's not going to be in a plaintext format anyway, is it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter As I have the option to insert \n, why cannot I have the current option?!

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Comment: @user3165438: I don't know why you keep referring to me as TimSchmelter, but using `\n` won't work in Word anyway. Again, Word documents aren't plain-text documents...

Comment: @Jon there is a deleted comment by a user with that name; presumably the origin of the confusion

Comment: @MarcGravell: I wondered whether that was the case the first time, but it seemed to happen twice. Ah well...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The is the form-feed ("FF") character:

```
string formFeed = "\f";
```

If there wasn't an pre-defined escape sequence for it, you could also use the fact that it is ASCII value 12, hex `C`, hence:

```
string formFeed = "\xC";
```

But: it depends on whether this character is used by your UI. Most UI devices will *not* do anything special with this character.

Comment: @user3165438 try it and let me know ;p

Comment: I think "\f" is also that character.

Comment: @MarcGravell, Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I looked for! Just let me know the link you know it from. Thanks

Comment: @MatthewWatson you are quite correct; I had to look it up, though - it isn't one I've ever needed to use!

Comment: @user3165438 see the update ala Matthew Watson's comment

Comment: Where is your knowledge from?

Comment: @user3165438 Page Break (AKA Form Feed) is a well-known ASCII character. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break for example.

Comment: @user3165438 the language specification

Comment: @MarcGravell  Misunderstand where is the "language specification" located. Tnx

Comment: If you have VS2013, it is in the Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC#/Specifications/1033 folder. It is also available in other locations. Look for the "Character literals" section. Or in places like this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple answer No.

The escape characters (`\n`, `\t`) and the whole string outputting is based a console based approach, ie 'infinitely' long with unlimited line length.

Page Breaks would differ per paper size, paper orientation, font size, line length and no of lines.

Comment: True but a page break could be enforced into the text, then this text may be sent to printer, a document such as MS-Word, etc.

Comment: @NoChance it would be interesting if Word honored the `\f` mentioned in @MarcGravell's answer...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it does. However, you need to open the text file containing the x'0C' using  MS-WORD or an RTF reader/writer first.

Answer (score 0):

Try using StringBuilder:

```
string string1 = "string 1";
string string2 = "string 2";
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder()
.AppendLine(string1)
.AppendLine("")
.AppendLine(string2);

string finalString = stringBuilder.ToString();
```