# Ruby, regexp: what is \r and \f?

Tags: ruby, regex

All I found again and again was this:

```
[\s\t\r\n\f]    \s  Whitespace character
```

Two questions:

1. I know that `\n` is new line, `\t` is tab, but what is `\r` and `\f`?
2. How do I search for them? What keyword should I use in Google?

Comment: They are more whitespace characters. `\r` matches a carriage return while `\f` matches a form-feed character.

Comment: Found this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: If you found that in a regex as a character class, it is completely redundant: `[\s\t\r\n\f]` is equivalent to `\s`.

Answer (score 1):

carriage return and form feed respectively. As for how to google, "whitespace characters" worked for me