# Char 'FF' Meaning in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2

[image]

What is this "FF" meaning ? 
When I was posting a form this char make submits errors.

Answer (score 4):

the `FF` character is a Form Feed character. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed) answer for details on the distinctions between CR (Carriage Return) LF (Line Feed) and FF