# Selenium not recognizing user input in Python

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am working through a book repository, specifically chapter 5 of Test-Driven Development, which can be found at this repository: https://github.com/hjwp/book-example/tree/chapter_05 . When I attempt to run the functional tests, which create a simple POST form, submit some input, and then check to see whether the input has been rendered, I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "book-example-chapter_05/functional_tests.py", line 45, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
    self.check_for_row_in_list_table('1: Buy peacock feathers')
  File "book-example-chapter_05/functional_tests.py", line 18, in check_for_row_in_list_table
    self.assertIn(row_text, [row.text for row in rows])
AssertionError: '1: Buy peacock feathers' not found in ['']

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It seems from a discussion on the mailing list that this might be due to the browser not receiving the 'ENTER' key. When I change the line to `inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers\n')`, to directly send a new line character, I get the following error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later (__main__.NewVisitorTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "book-example-chapter_05/functional_tests.py", line 44, in test_can_start_a_list_and_retrieve_it_later
    inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  File "/Users/r/virtualenvs/r/bin/python3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 322, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "/Users/r/virtualenvs/r/bin/python3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 448, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/r/virtualenvs/r/bin/python3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 196, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/r/virtualenvs/r/bin/python3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 181, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
    at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9348)
    at Utils.getElementAt (file:///var/folders/k5/t81w4vh94rg1ps_h5tb_vbr00000gn/T/tmp0cz8wkgo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8942)
    at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///var/folders/k5/t81w4vh94rg1ps_h5tb_vbr00000gn/T/tmp0cz8wkgo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9980)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///var/folders/k5/t81w4vh94rg1ps_h5tb_vbr00000gn/T/tmp0cz8wkgo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12626)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///var/folders/k5/t81w4vh94rg1ps_h5tb_vbr00000gn/T/tmp0cz8wkgo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12643)
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/k5/t81w4vh94rg1ps_h5tb_vbr00000gn/T/tmp0cz8wkgo/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:623)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.511s
```

so that seems to suggest that there is an error with the DOM tree, and the next element it tries to find (one with an id equal to 'id_list_table') cannot be found.

Why is this the case? How can I have Selenium test the addition of a list item and its existence in the table I've created?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that the selenium `runserver` command is unique to each app -- I was running the functional tests from the NEW (correct) repository, but I hadn't restarted my server with the NEW repository, I was using a server that was started using my OLD repository. Restarted the server and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use `\n`. If you want to send the enter key via selenium you would do:

```
 inputbox.send_keys('Buy peacock feathers')
 inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

`\n` is a linefeed. This basically means it ends the current line. Check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328/4971218) that explains in-depth.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I have tried using the syntax that you recommended - that is actually the original syntax in the repository. Unfortunately, that leads to the first error message in my original question.

Comment: Are you using the code directly from the github repo?

Comment: Yup. I'm using exactly the code that is in the chapter 5 branch. Without any modifications, it gives me the first error message posted. I've tried running it both in python 2 and python 3, though it is intended to be run in python 3.

Comment: It works fine with 2.7 for me.  Try `inputbox.send_keys(u'\ue007')` in place of `inputbox.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`? Also, what does your list_items table look like?

Comment: @orange1 actually the first error is not an error. It's your test assertion failing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too. I missed the `name=item_text` on the `input` of the `home.html`.

I'm not sure why I forgot that in the `view`, `request.POST.get('item_text', '')` looks for an `input` with that `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of problem before, and to work around it I usually first try a submit and then send a `return key`.

This is an extract from my custom wrapping class. `elem` would be your input element.

```
    try:
        self.debug("Trying regular submit")
        elem.submit()
    except:
        self.debug("Regular submit failed, sending RETURN key")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: +1 for using submit() method, this fixed a problem for me where Keys.ENTER was adding \ue007 to the output.  What I don't see, is why you would put an exception handler around it, particularly with a catchall handler when catching an actual type would illuminate the reasoning a bit.