# powershell cannot write newline character

Tags: powershell

> "b`nc" | out-file "a.txt"

output is:

> bc

What is the correct way to write a string containing a newline character.

THanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows system use carriage return + endline (\r\n) like this :

```
"b`r`nc" | out-file "c:\temp\a.txt"
```

if you want Something which work on multi-plateform try this:

```
'b' + [environment]::NewLine + 'c' | out-file "c:\temp\a.txt"
```

Answer (score 3):

You will occasionally need to use a 'carriage return' in conjunction with newline to get a new line to appear. Try this:

```
"b`r`nc" | out-file "a.txt"
```

For more information on carriage returns, you can [read this on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328/5220391)

Answer (score -2):

If you open with Notepad++, you'll see the line break. Also, if you run

```
Get-Content a.txt
```

You'll see the line break there too.

Issue here is encoding. For this to work:

```
"b`nc" | out-file a.txt -Encoding ascii
```

That should open properly in notepad.

Comment: I tested ``"b`nc" | out-file a.txt -Encoding ascii`` and found that when opening notepad, the line break was not there. I did see it in Notepad++.