# Why am I getting extra character while displaying a path in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Why am I getting extra characters while displaying a path in Python 3.X ?

> > > path = 'c:\flag'

```
>>> path 
'c:\x0clag'
```

Comment: additional info will be helpful like python version, os etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at: [What are carriage return, linefeed, and form feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed)

This is an old escape symbol used in older printers to advance ***'\f'***orward to the next page.

If you don't want this to show up, just add an `r` before your text:

Input:

```
path = r'c:\flag'
path
```

Output:

```
'c:\\flag'
```

Or just put double backslashes instead of one yourself:

```
path = 'c:\\flag'
```