# \n doesn't work in the body value of a mailto: link

Tags: html, mailto

I'm trying setting up a mailto: link with a body bigger than one line.

I tried \n to start a new line but it shows up in mail body as characters and doesn't start a new line:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?Subject=test&body=test \n test \n test \n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%0D%0A` in place of `\n`, due to url encoding. `%0D` is the url encoding for Carriage Return, `%0A` is the url encoding for Line Feed.

[Here's an answer that explains what each mean.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328/3399534)

In your example, it'll come out like this:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com&subject=test&body=test%0D%0Atest%0D%0Atest%0D%0A">mail</a>
```

Also note that `subject` should be all lowercase, otherwise you'll end up with `Subject=test` as the subject itself.

Comment: Whats the difference between this and the above mentioned %0A

Comment: Windows tends to use CRLF `(%0D%0A)`, whereas older macs and linux computers will use either CR `(%0D)` or LF `(%0A)`. It shouldn't make a huge amount of difference, but I've always used CRLF to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

You should use URL encoding, therefore the solution is `%0A`. 
In your example:

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com?Subject=test&body=test%0Atest%0Atest%0A"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly fine!