# Can't get printers or .pdf to do a formfeed with \x0c or \f in c code

Tags: c, pdf

I can't get many printers or **PDF** file to do a formfeed in **C** with `\x0c` or `\f` in `printf`

```c
printf("\f");
printf("\x0c");
```

Just prints a strange character. Any way to get it to take ansi ascii?

Comment: Hmmm, try enclosing it within newlines: `putchar('\n'); putchar('\f'); putchar('\n');`

Comment: You might like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091524/what-are-carriage-return-linefeed-and-form-feed

Comment: you may need to look for the form feed character and insert a page break manually there https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/6994n0/creating_a_new_page_in_a_pdf_from_a_formfeed/ https://forum.aspose.com/t/create-a-new-page-from-text-file-using-form-feed/176718/7