# How to solve "ECitMatch() got multiple values for argument 'bdata'"?

Tags: python, bioservices

I am new to use `bioservices` Python package. Now I am going to use that to retrieve PMIDs for two citations, given the specified information and this is the code I have tried:

```
from bioservices import EUtils
s = EUtils()
print(s.ECitMatch("pubmed",retmode="xml", bdata="proc+natl+acad+sci+u+s+a|1991|88|3248|mann+bj|Art1|%0Dscience|1987|235|182|palmenberg+ac|Art2|"))
```

But it occurs an error:

> "TypeError: ECitMatch() got multiple values for argument 'bdata'".

Could anyone help me to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have an unnamed argument (`pubmed`); if you look at the [source code](https://bioservices.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/bioservices/eutils.html#EUtils.ECitMatch), you can see that the first argument should be `bdata`; if you provide the arguments like you do, it is, however, unclear whether `bdata` is `"pubmed"` or the named argument `bdata`, therefore the error you obtain.

You can reproduce it with this minimal example:

```
def dummy(a, b): 
   return a, b

dummy(10, a=3)
```

will return

> TypeError: dummy() got multiple values for argument 'a'

If you remove `"pubmed"`, the error disappears, however, the output is still incomplete:

```
from bioservices import EUtils

s = EUtils()

print(s.ECitMatch("proc+natl+acad+sci+u+s+a|1991|88|3248|mann+bj|Art1|%0Dscience|1987|235|182|palmenberg+ac|Art2|"))
```

returns

```
'proc+natl+acad+sci+u+s+a|1991|88|3248|mann+bj|Art1|2014248\n'
```

so only the first publication is taken into account. You can get the results for both by using [the correct carriage return character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098328/1534017) `\r`:

```
print(s.ECitMatch(bdata="proc+natl+acad+sci+u+s+a|1991|88|3248|mann+bj|Art1|\rscience|1987|235|182|palmenberg+ac|Art2|"))
```

will return

```
proc+natl+acad+sci+u+s+a|1991|88|3248|mann+bj|Art1|2014248
science|1987|235|182|palmenberg+ac|Art2|3026048
```

I think you neither have to specify `retmod` nor the database (`pubmed`); if you look at the source code I linked above you can see:

```
query = "ecitmatch.cgi?db=pubmed&retmode=xml"
```

so seems it always uses `pubmed` and `xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues here: syntaxic and a bug.

The correct syntax is:

```py
    from bioservices import EUtils
    s = EUtils()
    query = "proc+natl+acad+sci+u+s+a|1991|88|3248|mann+bj|Art1|%0Dscience|1987|235|182|palmenberg+ac|Art2|"
    print(s.ECitMatch(query))
```

Indeed, the underlying service related to ICitMatch has only one database (pubmed) and one format (xml) hence, those 2 parameters are not available : there are hard-coded. Therefore, only one argument is required: your query.

As for the second issue, as pointed above and reported [on the bioservices issues page](https://github.com/cokelaer/bioservices/issues/169), your query would return only one publication. This was an issue with the special character %0D (in place of a return carriage) not being interpreted corectly by the URL request. This carriage character (either \n, \r or %0d) is now taken into account in the latest version on github or from pypi website if you use version 1.7.5

Thanks to [willigot](https://github.com/willigott) for filling the issue on bioservices page and bringing it to my attention.

disclaimer: i'm the main author of bioservices