# Fixing Sublime Text 2 line endings?

Tags: sublimetext2, line-endings

Here is my `Settings - User` config:

```
{
    "auto_indent": true,
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Twilight.tmTheme",
    "default_line_ending": "LF",
    "detect_indentation": true,
    "font_size": 10.0,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_to_bracket": false,
    "smart_indent": true,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
    "use_tab_stops": true
}
```

Comment to `default_line_ending` option says:
[image: Comment to default_line_ending option]

When I create a new file, I check line ending here:

[image: Check line ending]

As you can see it's still Windows...
Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried clicking "Unix", closing and then reopening?

Comment: @PreetKukreti Yes. After reopening it's "Windows" again. It only works for the current file, not the new file.

Comment: @an1zhegorodov did you save the file before ? that worked for me...

Comment: Yeah. after saving the file it worked for me too.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

The comment states

```
// Determines what character(s) are used to terminate each line in new files.
// Valid values are 'system' (whatever the OS uses), 'windows' (CRLF) and
// 'unix' (LF only).
```

You are setting

`"default_line_ending": "LF",`

You should set

`"default_line_ending": "unix",`

Comment: I have the same problem but i'm correctly setting `"default_line_ending": "unix"`, i dot't know why the hell that doesn't work! Its driving me mad! I've research a little and apparently it has no useful fix.

Comment: @acrespo Are you sure it's not being overridden by another preferences file? Sublime has lots of them :) - If you've specified one kind of line ending in your syntax specific prefs, it will override user prefs, which in turn override global prefs

Comment: I've never changed any of the syntax prefs, but i'm currently using rails syntax prefs, perhaps it's that? How can i see those settings?

Comment: @acrespo On OSX it's `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User` - I imagine it's a similar path on windows/linux if you're using those.

Comment: I've added the config to syntax prefs but still not working (the file with the settings was previously empty, so that couldn't be overriding anything). I seriously don't know what the heck is wrong with this.

Comment: @acrespo I really doubt I can help, you can double check what it's actually set to by bringing up the python console (ctrl + backtick) and running `view.settings().get('default_line_ending')` - Maybe they're set correctly in Sublime and getting messed up elsewhere.

Comment: setting "default_line_ending": "unix", works fine on new files.. but not on existing(older) files. Does anyone know how to change that behavior?

Comment: This can only be done manually, would be really helpful if this was automated. You can change this as seen in the image above View->Line Endings->Unix @soothsayer

Comment: @soothsayer, for existing files, select all the text, then `view` -> `line endings` -> `unix`.  Then save the document.

Comment: is this the same settings for Sublime3?

Answer (score 9):

The [EditorConfig project](http://editorconfig.org/) ([Github link](https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime)) is another very viable solution. Similar to sftp-config.json and .sublime-project/workspace sort of file, once you set up a .editorconfig file, either in project folder or in a parent folder, every time you save a file within that directory structure the plugin will automatically apply the settings in the dot file and automate a few different things for you. Some of which are saving Unix-style line endings, adding end-of-file newline, removing whitespace, and adjusting your indent tab/space settings.

---

## QUICK EXAMPLE

Install the EditorConfig plugin in Sublime using Package Control; then place a file named `.editorconfig` in a parent directory (even your home or the root if you like), with the following content:

```
[*]
end_of_line = lf
```

That's it. This setting will automatically apply Unix-style line endings whenever you save a file within that directory structure. You can do more cool stuff, ex. trim unwanted trailing white-spaces or add a trailing newline at the end of each file. For more detail, refer to the example file at https://github.com/sindresorhus/editorconfig-sublime, that is:

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

The `root = true` line means that EditorConfig won't look for other `.editorconfig` files in  the upper levels of the directory structure.

Comment: Insufficiently aggressive. I need the plugin to identify the chain of people who lead to the file having crlf and punch each of them in the face. And then save it with lf.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem, i had installed this plugin and it was taking the wrong config from the .config file

Answer (score 1):

to chnage line endings from LF to CRLF:

open Sublime and follow the steps:-

1 press Ctrl+shift+p then install package name line unify endings

then again press Ctrl+shift+p

2 in the blank input box type "Line unify ending "

3 Hit enter twice

Sublime may freeze for sometimes and as a result will change the line endings from LF to CRLF

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to **modify all files of a project** at once (batch) is through [Line Endings Unify](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Line%20Endings%20Unify) package:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> type *inst* + choose *Install Package*.
2. Type *line end* + choose *Line Endings Unify*.
3. Once installed, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> + type *end* + choose *Line Endings Unify*.
4. **OR** (instead of 3.) copy:

   ```
   {
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"],
    "command": "line_endings_unify"
   },
   ```

   to the *User* array (right pane, after the opening `[`) in *Preferences -> KeyBindings* + press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1552782/6225838):

> - The Carriage Return (**CR**) character (`0x0D`, `\r`) [...] Early Macintosh operating systems (OS-9 and earlier).
> - The Line Feed (**LF**) character (`0x0A`, `\n`) [...] UNIX based systems (Linux, Mac OSX)
> - The End of Line (**EOL**) sequence (`0x0D 0x0A`, `\r\n`) [...] (non-Unix: Windows, Symbian OS).

If you have ***node_modules*, *build* or other auto-generated folders, delete them before running** the package.

When you run the package:

1. you are asked at the bottom to choose which **file extensions** to search through a comma separated list (type the only ones you need to speed up the replacements, e.g. `js,jsx`).
2. then you are asked which **Input line ending to use**, e.g. if you need **LF**  type `\n`.
3. press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and wait until you see an alert window with *LineEndingsUnify Complete*.