# Why can't I save files in Sublime Text opened from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext3

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Sublime Text 3 in Windows 7.

I set up Sublime Text 3 as an external editor using the [steps outlined here](http://www.helleboreconsulting.com/index.php/blog/111-sublime-visual-studio-integration).

The file correctly opens to the current line as expected, however if I try to save the file in Sublime Text I get this error:

[image]

**EDIT:  The files are all marked as read-only, although VS opens and saves them without incident.  What can I do to remove the read-only flag when editing in ST?**

Comment: If the files are marked read only, then Sublime won't be able to save them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the line endings of the files after you edit them in sublime? make sure they are CR+LF
This may help [fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings)

Comment: Line endings are indeed Windows.