# Why doesn't my commands work in shell scripts but in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I face two problems, whose cause might be the same, which is why I post them in one question.

This is my little shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget "https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.2-linux-i686.tar.bz2"
```

Then I say `./script`.

I get `bash: ././script: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Then I say to myself, okay, try `bash script` instead of `./script`.

It seems to work, but the URL is then:

```
--2013-12-31 12:24:55--  https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.2-
linux-i686.tar.bz2%0D
Resolving phantomjs.googlecode.com... 173.194.69.82, 2a00:1450:4008:c01::52
Connecting to phantomjs.googlecode.com|173.194.69.82|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2013-12-31 12:25:01 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Do you recognize that my URL has an `2%0D` appended in line 2 after the file name?

**When I run the command in my shell itself, not as a script, it works totally fine.**

Do these two problems have the same root? Why is there a `2%0D` appended? I already looked for an empty space but did not find it.

Comment: What does `which bash` give you?

Comment: Yes, I did create the file with a Windows editor using a shared folder! @Barmar: What do you mean by that? @PeterSW: `which bash`? It says `/bin/bash`

Comment: @VusP: I did that, but I also edited the file on Linux afterwards.

Comment: My first comment was in response to another user's possible duplicate comment. He's since deleted it, so I'll delete my response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you edited your script probably with an editor creating DOS line endings (\r\n).  Use another editor or convert it with a tool like `dos2unix`

Comment: Both problems were indeed solved by the same solution. Thank you very much. After creating the file using `nano` in Linux, it worked.

Comment: dos2unix file; chmod 755 file   since dos2unix will strip permissions

Answer (score 1):

You should change your EOL conversion to Unix like.
If you're working on Windows, you can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'm using Sublime. Someone showed how to do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings