# Python: SimpleHTTPServer content length error

Tags: python, html, http-status-codes, simplehttpserver

I'm trying to use the built-in `SimpleHTTPServer` in Python to serve a static page locally. I start it with `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`.

At the moment, the HTML is just

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi
    </body>
</html>
```

The server returns the page with status 200 but the browser console says `ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` and won't render anything. If I change the content to single line of text it shows up fine. Adding another line breaks it again. Per the comments, it seems like the problem is with newlines. I'm writing this in Sublime Text (on Windows) and using Chrome to view, if that helps.

Comment: Please share the code of how you are reading the content. There could be issues due to things like newline,spaces etc. which your code might not be  parsing correctly since I recall something similar

Comment: works on mine, get a title of `Test` and text saying `Hi`

Comment: It definitely seems like a newline issue - I updated the question with some more info. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be a Sublime Text issue. Just had to change the line endings in `View > Line Endings` to `Unix`.

Big ups to this post:

[Fixing Sublime Text 2 line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings)

Comment: Fix the code that sets `Content-Length`. It should be calculated correctly whether the newline is `\n` or `\r\n`.