# change line endings in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, newline

how could I change line endings to sublime default in existing file?
there is no problem with line endings when creating new files in sublime (default line endings property works well)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can see and convert line endings in:

**View** -> **Line Endings**

Comment: You have to save the file.

Comment: sure, it mark file as changed, I save it, but when open from linux viwer it shows problems at the end of the lines

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych what line ending are you saving it as, and what are the "problems at the end of the lines"?

Comment: Hmmm, thats odd, I haven't tested it thoroughly, but something changes because notepad displays the two versions differently. But then again I'm on ST3 maybe thats why.

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych maybe this thread can provide some insight:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings