# Angular-Fullstack - grunt build not including javascript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, bower

OK I post this question on Angular-Fullstack's issue list on gitHub so you can check it out there too to see if there are any additional posts that aren't on here. [git hub question](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/627)

Basically I'm getting the following output in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/images/loading.gif 404 (Not Found) (index):60
GET http://localhost:8080/app/assignment-meeting/prepare-senior/candidate/profile/_profile-ctrl.js  (index):102
GET http://localhost:8080/app/assignment-meeting/prepare-senior/candidate-list/candidates-list-controller.js  (index):100
GET http://localhost:8080/app/assignment-meeting/prepare-senior/candidate/_candidate-ctrl.js  (index):101
GET http://localhost:8080/app/assignment-meeting/prepare-senior/candidate/summary/_summary-ctrl.js  (index):103
GET http://localhost:8080/app/home/home-controller.js  (index):104
GET http://localhost:8080/components/services/candidate-services.js  (index):109
GET http://localhost:8080/components/auth/User.js  (index):106
GET http://localhost:8080/app/routes.js  (index):105
GET http://localhost:8080/components/directives/napi-ck-editor.js  (index):108
GET http://localhost:8080/components/auth/user-service.js  (index):107
GET http://localhost:8080/components/services/http-helper.js  (index):110
GET http://localhost:8080/components/services/menu-services.js 404 (Not Found)
```

It seems like grunt build can't find my script files located within the injector sections of my index.html page. If I recopy the originally created index.html file that the generator created and copy all of the code above the "Google Analytics" section over, then  it will work fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work as it doesn't seem to show there being any actual difference in the code. The page doesn't show a single line being different. The only thing that I thought might be causing the problem is that the line endings might be getting changed when I commit it to git and then it has issues. Truthfully I'm in the dark on this one. I post this question on a couple different forms so I'm tired of retyping it...so if you want to read my git hub post (link above), it might be better worded.

Thanks for the help.

Update:

Sorry I should have attached my grunt file so it could be read and noted that there's a grunt.registerTask called "build." I didn't attach it because I haven't really changed it from the default one made by angular-fullstack and figure other could simply view that as a reference...but attaching it is simpler and better:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Configurable paths for the application
    var appConfig = {
        app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
        dist: 'src/main/webapp'
    };

    // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
        useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
        ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
        cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
        protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
        injector: 'grunt-asset-injector'
    });

//    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        yeoman: {
            // configurable paths
            client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
            dist: 'src/main/webapp'
        },
        watch: {
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['wiredep']
            },
            injectJS: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                    '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
                    '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'],
                tasks: ['injector:scripts']
            },
            injectCss: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
                ],
                tasks: ['injector:css']
            },
            jsTest: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
                ],
                tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
            },
            injectSass: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['injector:sass']
            },
            sass: {
                files: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
                tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            livereload: {
                files: [
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.css',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.html',
                    '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                    '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
                ],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/client/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./client/bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            connect.static('.tmp'),
                            connect.static('test'),
                            connect().use(
                                '/client/bower_components',
                                connect.static('./client/bower_components')
                            ),
                            connect.static(appConfig.app)
                        ];
                    }
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
                }
            }
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
            ],
            test: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
                ]
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.openshift',
                        '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/'
                }]
            }
        },


        // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
        wiredep: {
            target: {
                src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
                ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/',
                exclude: [/bootstrap-sass-official/, /bootstrap.js/, '/json3/', '/es5-shim/', /bootstrap.css/, /font-awesome.css/ ]
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
                        '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
            options: {
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                flow: {
                    html: {
                        steps: {
                            js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
                            css: ['cssmin']
                        },
                        post: {}
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        cssmin: {
            options: {
                root: 'client'
            }
        },
        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
            js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
            options: {
                assetsDirs: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
                ],
                // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
                patterns: {
                    js: [
                        [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },

//        htmlmin: {
//            dist: {
//                options: {
//                    collapseWhitespace: true,
//                    conservativeCollapse: true,
//                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
//                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
//                    removeOptionalTags: true
//                },
//                files: [{
//                    expand: true,
//                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
//                    src: ['*.html', 'app/**/*.html'],
//                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
//                }]
//            }
//        },
//        uglify: {
//           dist: {
//             files: {
//               '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
//                 '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
//               ]
//             }
//           }
//        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
        // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
        ngAnnotate: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/concat',
                    src: '*/**.js',
                    dest: '.tmp/concat'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
        ngtemplates: {
            options: {
                // This should be the name of your apps angular module
                module: 'napiRest',
                htmlmin: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
                },
                usemin: 'app/app.js'
            },
            main: {
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
                src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
                dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
            },
            tmp: {
                cwd: '.tmp',
                src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
                dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
            }
        },

        // Replace Google CDN references
        cdnify: {
            dist: {
                html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/*.html']
            }
        },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'bower_components/**/*',
                        'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
                        'assets/fonts/**/*',
                        'index.html'
                    ]
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/images',
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
                    src: ['generated/*']
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        'package.json'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
                dest: '.tmp/',
                src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'sass'
            ],
            test: [
                'sass'
            ],
            dist: [
                'sass',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        },

        // Test settings
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
                singleRun: true
            }
        },

        mochaTest: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
        },

        protractor: {
            options: {
                configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
            },
            chrome: {
                options: {
                    args: {
                        browser: 'chrome'
                    }
                }
            }
        },


        // Compiles Sass to CSS
        sass: {
            server: {
                options: {
                    loadPath: [
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
                    ],
                    compass: false
                },
                files: {
                    '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
                }
            }
        },

        injector: {
            options: {

            },
            // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
            scripts: {
                options: {
                    transform: function(filePath) {
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
                        return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
                    },
                    starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
                    endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
                        ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
                            '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.js',
                            '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
                            '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
                    ]
                }
            },

            // Inject component scss into app.scss
            sass: {
                options: {
                    transform: function(filePath) {
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
                        return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
                    },
                    starttag: '// injector',
                    endtag: '// endinjector'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
                        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
                    ]
                }
            },

            // Inject component css into index.html
            css: {
                options: {
                    transform: function(filePath) {
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
                        filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
                        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
                    },
                    starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
                    endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
                        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
    grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
        grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

        var done = this.async();

        setTimeout(function () {
            grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
            done();
        }, 3000);
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'wait', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'injector:sass',
            'concurrent:server',
            'injector',
            'wiredep',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'wait',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run(['serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
        if (target === 'client') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'injector:sass',
                'concurrent:test',
                'injector',
                'autoprefixer',
                'karma'
            ]);
        }

        else if (target === 'e2e') {
            return grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'injector:sass',
                'concurrent:test',
                'injector',
                'wiredep',
                'autoprefixer',
                'connect:test',
                'protractor'
            ]);
        }

        else grunt.task.run([
                'test:client'
            ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'useminPrepare',
        'autoprefixer',
        'ngtemplates',
        'concat',
        'ngAnnotate',
        'copy:dist',
        'cdnify',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'rev',
        'usemin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: I am having similar problem. 
Can you confirm that your public/index.html is having all the script and stylesheet files?
If I remove injector tag from client/index.html then it works fine.

Comment: @vinesh So you simply removed the `<!-- injector:js -->` tags from your index page and then it worked correctly? Are you manually inserting any new js files you create into your index page?

Currently the script and stylesheets are injected correctly and work find with the `grunt serve` command. It's when I use the `grunt build` command that problems occur. 

I'm not 100% if that answered your question.

Comment: `grunt serve` works correctly for me too. So I don't need to manually insert new files in index page. Its `grunt build` which is not running as expected with `<!-- injector:js -->` tags in `client/index.html`. I asked you if your generated index file contains all the scripts as in the original index page? You can refer to my comment at https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/370

Answer (score 5):

I've encountered xactly the same problem here.
After hours of file by file comparison.
I've finally solved it. So I thought I would share what has worked for me.

I'm working on windows, and simply change the line ending to Unix style for "index.html" in my text editor (I'm using sublime text by the way) solve the problem. "Windows" line ending make the script bug it seems.

Hope that will help.

Meg4mi

Comment: Thanks I figure that out too, but I'm curious did you find a way to make the line ending stay in Unix format for all users? I mean I don't want to have to tell everyone to change the line ending in their editor. I have this in my .editorconfig file but it doesn't seem to work: 

`end_of_line = lf`

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for me. How i converted the line endings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's because of grunt-injector line endings. See [this issue](https://github.com/klei/grunt-injector/issues/12).

To avoid that you could configure grunt injector to work with default grunt line endings:

```
injector: {
   options: {
      lineEnding: grunt.util.linefeed
   },
   ...
}
```

Doing that, you will have to configure your Git line endings setting in case you work on different platforms. Assuming you are on Windows and pulling a file from Linux, you will obtain after the injection process a mixed LF and CR/LF file (LF in all the HTML file and CR/LF bewteen `<!-- injector:js -->` tags) and the grunt-build plugin will not work.

You can use [this](https://github.com/SublimeText/LineEndings) Sublime Text plugin to see line endings on your file.

Comment: And make sure its a newer version of grunt-asset-injector as the lineEnding option was added in a newer version than that released by angular-fullstack for OpenShift.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because 'build' isn't a registered task within the Gruntfile.js

The registered tasks are:
bump, stage, generateDemo, releaseDemoBuild, updateFixtures, installFixtures, test, demo, releaseDemo

I think you maybe want releaseDemoBuild?

grunt releaseDemoBuild

Comment: Check out the update I just posted. The Gruntfile.js has a register task that is created by the generator. So it should work, and normally does, until this strange error pops up...with what seems to be no reasoning.