# How to format a string for Outlook

Tags: cocoa, email, outlook, format, applescript

I'm trying to format a string for a new email in outlook but when I use "\n" it doesn't make a return.

Is there a way to fix this? I'm using cocoa to build this app. And I need to have the returns.

Thanks

Comment: how are you getting that string *into* outlook?  Applescript or Apple Events or via a plug-in or?  also, have you tried using "\r" instead of "\n"?  Or what happens when you try ["\r\n" (i.e. CRLF)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)?

Comment: I'm sending it through an Applescript, and when I try \r or \r\n it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have the issue. To fix it just use the html tag 
 instead of \n. Outlook must convert the string into an html string, and 
 is the break tag for HTML.