# The difference between \n and <br /> in php

Tags: php

I was studying php with tutorial. I recognized that in php 
 is sometimes use like this

```
echo $myString."<br />"
```

Suddenly, there came another in the tutorial "\n" and I got confused. Can I use it just like I use

```
<br />
```

?

So like this?

```
echo $mySting."\n"
```

Is it like a html tag?
What's the difference between

```
<br /> and \n?
```

Comment: `<br />` is html markup; `\n` is a unix newline

Comment: ```\n``` is a newline in the code level which does not translate to ```<br>``` in HTML as HTML does not honor whitespace

Comment: @Dominik - HTML recognises `\n` when it's within `<pre>` or `<xmp>` tags

Comment: @MarkBaker indeed but that seems almost too advanced for this question ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<br />` is a HTML line-break, whereas `\n` is a newline character in the source code.

In other words, `<br />` will make a new line when you view the page as rendered HTML, whereas \n will make a new line when you view the source code.

Alternatively, if you're outputting to a console rather than somewhere that will be rendered by a web browser then `\n` will create a newline in the console output.

Answer (score 4):

`\n` is a [new line character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) (a literal new line as you would type in your code).

```
$newline = "
";

var_dump($newline === "\n");
// true
```

You can also use the [PHP constant `PHP_EOL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-eol) (end of line).  Note, that `'\n'` will render `\n` as a literal string; you must use double quotes to have it rendered as a new line character.  Also note, that my above example may actually output false..since sometimes [new lines are rendered as `\r\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types).

---

`<br />` is an [HTML element for a line break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br).  This will show up as a new line when HTML is rendered in a browser.

---

The only time that `\n` will show up as a rendered line break in HTML, is when it is within a [`<pre>` (pre-formatted text) element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre).  Otherwise it would be the same as just formatting/indenting your HTML code:

```
<?php
echo "<html>\n\t<body>\n\t\tHello World!\n\t</body>\n</html>";
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
    <body>
        Hello World!
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

`\n` is a *new line feed* within the context of plain text, while `<br />` is *line break* within the context of HTML.

HTML can interpret `\n` when using preformatted blocks (e.g. `<pre>`), but it does not by default, and should not unless there is a specific use case (like when quoting, citing poetry, or showing code).

`<br />` should never be used to separate text that should otherwise be treated as a paragraph, heading or other group of text.

Comment: +1 for not recommending ```<br>``` for text formatting!

Comment: Dominik, with that, html should never be used for text formatting anyways, CSS should be! Unfortunately, these "24-hour-books" don't always mention that.

Comment: +1 against <br>. For the sake of completeness: The alternative is <p>.