# how to add new line on php

Tags: php, codeigniter, echo

i have a code to create star combined with number, the result that i have like this:

```
1*****2*****3*****4*****5
```

and the source code:

```
<?php
$max = 5;

for ($i=1; $i<=$max; $i++){
    for ($j=1; $j<=$max; $j++){
        if ($i==$j){
            echo "$j";
        }
        else{
            //echo "<br>";
            echo "*";   
        }
    }
}
?>
<br />
```

and the result that i want like this:

```
1 * * * * 
* 2 * * * 
* * 3 * * 
* * * 4 *
* * * * 5
```

How to add a new line on my code??

Comment: Just at the end of your second for loop?! (Don't forget to add the brackets)

Comment: I edited your question to include brackets, always add them, it helps a lot when other people look at your code

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$max = 5;
for ($i=1; $i<=$max; $i++) {
    for ($j=1; $j<=$max; $j++)   {
        if ($i==$j)
            echo "$j ";
        else   
            echo "* "; 
    }
    echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Ans of your code is: `1****<br/>*2***<br/>**3**<br/>***4*<br/>****5<br/>`
plz see:  https://3v4l.org/9pQHZ

Comment: I have sent a link of your answer... Just check it..!!

Comment: well it's an HTML-line break.. only difference is that `\n` is on the code itself.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026250/the-difference-between-n-and-br-in-php

Comment: Then why It's not showing proper in Online Editor??

Comment: This Question is not `tagged` as `HTML` but it is of `PHP`... Got my point? @severinolorillajr

Answer (score 1):

Change you code like this:

```
$max = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $max; $j++)
        if ($i == $j) {
            echo "$j";
        } else {
            echo "*";
        }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Check results [here](https://3v4l.org/SXHNJ)