# display newline on webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

[image: When I try to replace \n with <br/, it doesn't work as well.>][image: As seen in pic, newlines should be not like this. It should be jump to next line][image: This is my html code to display post message.]

How can I make newlines become normal and display in the right way?

Comment: Replace them with `<br>` elements.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working, please check the 1st pic.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're needing `<br>`tag.

From [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp):

> The `<br>` tag inserts a single line break.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working, please check the 1st pic.

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a new line used in plain text, `<br />` on the other hand is line break used in HTML

Answer (score 1):

In Flask you can create a template filter

eg:

```
@app.template_filter('nl2br')
def nl2br(s):
    return s.replace("\n", "<br />")
```

and use

```
{{rs.post.message|nl2br}}
```

Comment: I tried, but it is not working, please check the 1st pic.

Comment: Try autoescape off {% autoescape false %} {{rs.post.message}} {% endautoescape %}

Comment: It is working now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @AtulMishra for solve and Thanks Allen for your question

Answer (score 0):

> The only time that \n will show up as a rendered line break in HTML,
>   is when it is within a  (pre-formatted text) element.
>   [The difference between \n and <br /> in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026250/the-difference-between-n-and-br-in-php)

With the above quote being said, I suggest using `<br>` rather than `\n`.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working, please check the 1st pic.