# Assembly x86 on clarity over an instruction, very simple

Tags: assembly, x86

Could someone give me some background on what the instruction "call crlf" does? I am having some trouble finding good resources on whether or not I need this in my code. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an instruction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types

Comment: Look up `CALL` in the [Intel Software Developer Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals). `crlf` is some subroutine which you haven't shown us, so we can't possibly know what it does. By its name I'd guess that it prints a carriage return and a linefeed, but there's no way of knowing without seeing the code.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see now that this is an instruction to carry a line down or new line. It may be a specific direction to call within 32 bit x86 programming?

Comment: carriage return `CR` and line feed `LF` i.e `\r\n`, it's a method that just prints a `newline` [see here](http://www.answers.com/topic/crlf-computer-jargon)

Comment: Thank you James. I feel like there weren't too many concrete answers to the question before I asked. I don't really understand why this is getting negative feedback as a question, but thats fine. Thanks for all of your responses! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a procedure call to a procedure called "crlf". What does it do is anybody's guess; but it probably has to do with a newline sequence on Windows-based platforms. CR stands for character #13 aka carriage return, and LF is #10, line feed. In Windows, lines are terminated with CR/LF character pair. Some non-Windows tools respect them, too; notably, this is a line separator in some prominent Internet protocols such as HTTP.

The procedure prints CR/LF on the console, or stores them in some string buffer, or something. Without its code, it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

`Could someone give me some background on what the instruction "call crlf" does?`

When you use the **instruction** `call` in assembly, you are `jumping` to an `address`, executing from there until you hit a `ret` instruction and returning to where you called from, generally people call these labels and the associated code `subroutines, methods, functions, procedures` e.t.c.

Also depending on how the subroutines are implemented will depend on the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) *(how and where you pass arguments and get return values)* that you will need to follow.

---

`CRLF` is likely a `label` *(meaning a symbolic representation of an address)*

Which probably stands for `carriage return` & `line feed`.

Which stands for [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) `'\r'` & `'\n'`.

Which stands for hex `0xd` & `0xa` respectively.

---

**The differences between**  `'\r' & '\n'`

- `Mac` uses `'\r' CR` for newlines.
- `Unix/Linux` use `'\n' LF` for newlines.
- `Windows` uses `"\r\n" CRLF`

proof Windows does this is in this dump of a file called `text.txt` that contains 2 presses of the `enter` key;

```
c:\Users\James\Desktop>dump text.txt
0D 0A 0D 0A 0A -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  | .....-----------
```

and quickly on a Linux VM;

```
james@james-VirtualBox:~Files$ hexdump -C text.txt
00000000    0a 0a                                           |...|
00000002
```

I don't have a `mac` so i can't prove they use `'\r'` for newlines.

---

**For Background** *(where it comes from)*

Basically you need to think about `typewriters` & `printers` - [see this googled image](http://www.penguinpetes.com/images/Underwoodfive.jpg);

- [carriage return](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carriage_return):

  1) *"On a typewriter or computer printer, the action that returns it to the beginning of the line."*

  2) *"The control character (0x0D in ASCII, abbreviated as CR) that originally signaled a device to perform a carriage return, but now merely indicates the end of a line of text."*
- [line feed](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line_feed):

  1) *"On a typewriter, the action of the carriage roller to push the page up one, two or one and a half lines (as set elsewhere) when executing a carriage return."*

  2) *"The character (0x0a in ASCII) which advances the paper by one line in a teletype or printer"*