# Prevent Character Count Going Up By 2 On vbNewLine

Tags: vb.net

I'm having a problem with the character count in a textbox.

```
If e.KeyChar = ChrW(13) Then tsCount.Text = "Character Count: " & tbText.Text.Count - 2
```

Basically I want to prevent the character count going up by 2 when the user creates a new line in the textbox. I've tried that code above, but didnt really work.

Also, in my program the user cannot create a new line without having any text in the textbox by using 
the code below:

```
If tbText.Text = String.Empty And e.KeyChar = ChrW(13) Then e.Handled = True
```

tsCount is a label, and tbText is my textbox. Is it possible to prevent it by going up by 2?

Comment: In a Windows environment, a new line consists of two characters (Cr + Lf; carriage return + line feed). Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all new line characters by using [`String.Replace(String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before performing the measurement of length.

```
Dim newText As String = tbText.Text.Replace(vbNewLine, String.Empty)
tsCount.Text = newText.Count
```