# mongodb import error using makefile

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use mongoimport to import multiple collections. I do that in a .sh file "seed.sh" which contains the following :

```
mongoimport --db blog --collection users --file ./db/users.json --jsonArray
mongoimport --db blog --collection articles --file ./db/articles.json --jsonArray
```

I use makefile in cygwin64 terminal. The first import always fails. The second always succeeds. This holds true if I change the order of the collection that is being imported. I receive the error "Error parsing command line: unknown option jsonArray". What is the problem here?

Comment: try running it outside the script??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your seed.sh file currently has CRLF line ending. Convert to LF line ending for seed.sh to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of `CR LF` and `LF` characters line ending. Windows uses `CR LF` while Unix uses `LF`.
Now changing those two lines of yours to `mongoimport --db blog --collection users --file ./db/users.json --jsonArray && mongoimport --db blog --collection articles --file ./db/articles.json --jsonArray` will probably solve your problem.

for more information about line endings please refer to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types).