# How do I insert newline characters into Stata macro variables?

Tags: stata

I have a Stata plug-in that allows me to read SQL from a file, run it on my PostgreSQL server, and have the data delivered to Stata.

Unfortunately, a lot of my SQL relies on newlines being correctly parsed so as to generate correct (or even valid) SQL. For example,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM some_table
-- Require something to be true
WHERE some_boolean;
```

ends up in Stata as `SELECT * FROM some_table -- Require something to be true  WHERE some_boolean;`, which clearly doesn't work.

Here is the `.ado` file I use to read the data. I have tried many approaches, but can't find a way to put newlines into the `exec` variable.

```
program define loadsql
*! Load the output of an SQL file into Stata, version 1.4 (iandgow@gmail.com)
version 13.1
syntax using/, CONN(string)

#delimit;
tempname sqlfile exec line;

file open `sqlfile' using `"`using'"', read text;
file read `sqlfile' `line';

while r(eof)==0 {;
    local `exec' `"``exec'' ``line'' 
     "';
    file read `sqlfile' `line';
};

file close `sqlfile';

* display "`conn'";

pgload "`conn'" "``exec''", clear;
* pgload "``dsn''" "SELECT permno, date, abs(prc) AS prc FROM crsp.dsf LIMIT 10", clear;

end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you post **exactly** how the `pgload` syntax is supposed to be? I mean, substitute the local macros `conn` and `exec` with the appropriate text.

Comment: Here's an example call to `pgload`:

`pgload "dbname=crsp host=localhost" "SELECT permno, date, abs(prc) AS prc FROM crsp.dsf LIMIT 10"`.

What I want to be able to do is to pass `SELECT *\n
FROM some_table\n
-- Require something to be true\n
WHERE some_boolean;\n` to `pgload` where `\n` represents the newline character. As the code is, the newlines in the text file I load turn into spaces, to I get `SELECT * FROM some_table -- Require something to be true WHERE some_boolean;`, which doesn't work.

Comment: I just find it unusual that a Stata command requires inserting newline characters. If so, I think `pgload` itself should indicate the way. I've never faced or heard/read of such a situation (though I have a relatively short experience).

Comment: It's not Stata that is requiring this, but PostgreSQL (or SQL). SQL uses line-breaks to determine the end of comments that begin with `--`. In other words, I don't want PostgreSQL to treat `-- Require something to be true WHERE some_boolean;` as a comment; the `WHERE some_boolean` is meant to affect the result of the query.

Comment: Let me try again: what character(s) do you need the local `exec` (not the "variable") to hold? Put differently, what characters would SQL understand to be new lines? Is it `\n` or are you using `\n` as a placeholder for some character(s) you are hoping to find?

Comment: `\n` is the way to represent "newlines" in some languages. A literal `\n` is not what I am after. But it seems I can get this using `char(10)`. See my answer and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types

Your question prompted more research, which led to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `char(10)` (or perhaps `char(13) + char(10)` on Windows).

Thus, replace

```
local `exec' `"``exec'' ``line'' 
 "';
```

in the `.ado` file supplied in the question with

```
local `exec' = "``exec''" + char(10) + "``line''";
```