# Add a character ) to the end of every lines in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I'd like to add the `)` character (close bracket) to the end of all lines.

I see **CR** is the end symbol of every lines. (Menu > View > Show Symbol > Show end of line)

I tried to replace `\r` with `)\r` in Regular expression mode but it didn't work.

How do I do this?

Comment: Were you in extended mode?

Comment: @Maxqueue No I was in Regular expression mode, I've just changed to extended and voila. Thanks man!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `$` to match end of line in regular expression mode. Replace with `\(`, slash is to escape

[image]

Comment: this works too along with replace `\r` with `)\r` in `extended` mode

Answer (score 1):

You need to match extended or regular expression and replace "\n" with ")\n". At least this worked by me so far. According to this there can be differences though [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding can you check whether \n works in your case? just for curiosity...

Comment: No, replacing `\n` with `)\n` does not work in my case in both extended or regular expression mode because my end line symbol is `CR`, I need `\r`

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding Thanks!