# Notepad ++: Editing multiple txt files

Tags: file, text, notepad++, newline

I'd like to edit multiple (~2000) txt files in Notepad ++. To be more specific: I'd like to narrow the entire text of into a column with newlines.

Like so:

[image]

into:

[image]

Of course it is not as simple, because the Text is dynamic and contains brackets for certain terms that will later help a search engine (Those will however not become unfunctional when separated with a newline which comes in very handy).

I found out that I can do so easily with the Line Operation "Split Line" in the "Edit" tab. Now I just need to do it with the rest of the files. I wonder if that can be automated? As it is not a macro it could be kind of tricky. Another thing I thought of was using a RegEx in the "Find in Files" option. Something like "find n characters with n spaces in between them" then "replace the exact same chars with the same chars but add a newline at the end".
Or "make a newline every 7 spaces".
Not sure if that is a viable approach, though.
Im curious about what you think about this. Any Suggestions?

Comment: In *Find in Files*, try `(?:^|\G)(\S*(?:\h+\S+){7})\h*` as search regex pattern and `$1\n` as the replace with pattern.

Comment: Notepad ++ Output:
"Search "(?:^|\G)(\S*(?:\h+\S+){7})\h*" (0 hits in 0 files)"

Comment: Did you check *Regular expression* radio button?

Comment: Also, you need to use `Replace in Files` button.

Comment: No I didn't. Now I feel a little goofy for it. But now it worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Find in Files**, you may use

*Find What*: `(?:^|\G)(\S*(?:\h+\S+){7})\h*`
*Replace With*: `$1\n`

Do not forget to check the *Regular expression* radio button at the bottom.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:^|\G)` - either start of line or the end of the last successful match
- `(\S*(?:\h+\S+){7})` - Group 1 later referenced to with `$1` backreference in the replacement pattern, capturing 0+ non-whitespace symbols, followed with exactly 7 sequences of 1+ horizontal whitespaces and 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\h*` - zero or more  horizontal whitespaces

[image]

Comment: Some feedback on further usage: I did some test runs and it seems to have worked, but; I opened the files in Notepad++ and they are as the script formatted them. When I open them in Notepad, they are just normal like they where before! Like the script didn't even happen. Saving them manually, overwriting the file hasn't helped.

Comment: In Notepad, CRLF endings are used. Replace with `$1\r\n` to display Windows style line breaks.

Comment: Allright, of course. It displays properly now. All files are in UTF-8, should I use `$1\r\n` or `\n` then? If I want to display it to a user, i guess i should take `$1\r\n`

Comment: It does not depend on file encoding, but the tool and OS. In Windows, use `\r\n`, in Unix/Linux, use `\n`, in MacOS use `\r`. Notepad2 and Notepad++ work with any linebreak styles well.

Comment: That is really good to know. For anyone interested, I read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types).