# Unable to add new line in input file using linux machine

Tags: java, linux, windows, file

My requirement is to generate a text file.I added the new line in my file using bufferedWriter.newLine() its working fine in windows but its not working in linux.
I tried too many things but nothing is worked out so for.If i open the generated text file in notepad++ its show as line separated but in notepad it looks with out any line separator.In the console i can find the new line in both the platform but the file only windows has the new line but not in linux.

Below is my code

```
File file = new File(fileToWrite);
bufferedWrtier = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
LOGGER.debug("Line Separator 1:: "+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
LOGGER.debug("Line Separator 2:: "+System.lineSeparator());
LOGGER.debug("Line Separator 3:: "+SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR);
bufferedWrtier.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
bufferedWrtier.write(System.lineSeparator());
bufferedWrtier.write(SystemUtils.LINE_SEPARATOR);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!!!!!!

Local Machine Os: windows
Server Machine Os: Linux

Comment: Notepad can not handle the unix EOL which is only a LF. It can only handle the Windows CRLF. So it is no Problem with your program, it is a "problem" with Notepad.

Comment: @jens, then their is no fix for this??

Comment: The Windows Notepad.exe is a very basic application that cannot cope with text files with lines ending with Line Feed (a.k.a. Unix line separators). Your options are: (1) use another tool such as Notepad++; (2) copy the file to your Windows box using a copy utility that translates Unix line endings to Windows line endings.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou, can you please explain the second point in little bit briefly

Comment: @Madhesh You can if you use  `write("\r\n")` instead of `writeLine()`

Comment: @jens,I tried that also but no luck

Comment: @Madhesh But that should work, because this is the Windows EOL

Comment: @Jens.Its worked.thank u very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is a difference in newline representation, based on the OS you're using.

There are two control characters you need to know:

- CL - carriage return (`'\r'` or **0x0D** in hex)
- LF - line feed (`'\n'` or **0x0A** in hex)

Windows natively uses the CL+LF combination for newlines (`\r\n` combination, or two bytes) while Linux uses only LF (`\n`, one byte).

Notepad is a pretty limited tool and it can correctly interpret only the Windows combination - if it sees a sequence of two bytes - **0x0D** followed by **0x0A** in your file, it will display that as a new line.

If it only sees **0x0A** without **0x0D**, it will not treat it as a new line combination, but will display **0x0A** as a box (or it will just be ignored on Windows 10), since it is a non printable character.

To see effects of this, in Notepad++, turn on viewing of all characters:

> View -> Show symbol -> Show all characters

You will see that a Windows file has **CRLF**, while Unix-like has **LF**.

Unix-like will not be displayed correctly in notepad.

You can switch between Windows and Unix-like like this:

> Edit -> EOL conversion

I'd suggest reading [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) to learn more about it and a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types) to know more.