# What is "crlf" function in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to read a sql code. I saw a key at the first lines. It was "crlf".

Why they write that, anybody know?

Comment: Could you share the code?

Comment: Without a heck of a lot more information, it's going to be impossible for us to guess the right answer. An example of the code showing what you see would be a start...

Answer (score 3):

- `CR` is the carriage return.
- `LF` is the line feed.

`CR LF` sequence is used in Windows. Unix only uses `LF`. In Macintosh OS prior to Mac OS X `CR` was used.

Please refer the answer to [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types) for more answers and details on the same.