# Blank lines in text files: Ubuntu vs Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu

I have a text file which contains some data, with a number of blank lines which intersperse the data.

When opened in Ubuntu, I can see the blank lines, however on a windows machine all the data is displayed on the same line with no new lines at all.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: CRLF vs LF - different newlines on different platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between CR LF, LF and CR line break types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a text file there are characters that you can't see in the text editor that indicate a new line. On Windows it is `\n\r` and on Linux it is `\n`.

[Here is a good link that will explain this in a little more detail.](https://superuser.com/questions/374028/how-are-n-and-r-handled-differently-on-linux-and-windows)